# JavaScript: Invoking click-event of an anchor tag from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, onclick

I have a page with an anchor tag. In my JavaScript I am setting the `HREF` attribute of the anchor tag dynamically based on some if-else conditions. Now I want to invoke the click event of the anchor tag programmatically. I used the below code, but was not successful.

```
var proxyImgSrc="CostMetrics.aspx?Model=" + model +"&KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=410&width=650";

document.getElementById("proxyAnchor").href=proxyImgSrc;
document.getElementById("proxyAnchor").onclick;
```

Can any one tell me how to go ahead? I have a jQuery light box implementation(thickbox) on this link.

Kindly advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I get to set the path where the file should be downloaded?

because using this it's just downloading to the DOWNLOADS folder. i want to to save to the location of html file.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you have jQuery installed then why not just do this:

```
$('#proxyAnchor')[0].click();
```

Note that we use [0] to specify the first element. The jQuery selector returns a jQuery instance, and calling click() on that only calls click javascript handler, not the href. Calling click() on the actual element (returned by [0]) will follow the link in an href etc.

See here for an example to illustrate the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/8hyU9/

As to why your original code is not working - it is probably because you are calling `onclick`, and not `onclick()`. Without the parenthesis JavaScript will return whatever is assigned to the `onclick` property, not try to execute it.

Try the following simple example to see what I mean:

```
var f = function() { return "Hello"; };     
alert(f);
alert(f());
```

The first will display the actual text of the function, while the second will display the word "Hello" as expected.

Comment: For the use case of "follow the href defined in the anchor" [this answer fails](http://jsfiddle.net/SNdHW/show/)

Comment: @RoatinMarth Actually, it does work for that. Part of the problem is that you're using JSFiddle (Clicking the link itself doesn't work in JSFiddle). For a perfect example of it working in JSFiddle, try setting the target to _blank. Also, you didn't do [0]. I tested it without the target on my own server, and it worked just fine. So here's a "fixed" version for JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SNdHW/4/show/

Comment: Can I get to set the path where the file should be downloaded?

because using this it's just downloading to the DOWNLOADS folder. i want to to save to the location of html file.

Comment: @TheOneWhoSighs check the timestamps of this answer's edits. My comment was in reply to the original answer (the "pure jQuery" solution).

Answer (score 13):

You should call click event like this:

```
document.getElementById("proxyAnchor").click();
// $('#proxyAnchor').click();
```

but in your case you should set the window's location to a redirect page, if you want that.

Comment: Can I get to set the path where the file should be downloaded?

because using this it's just downloading to the DOWNLOADS folder. i want to to save to the location of html file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to invoke the `click` event. Not the "onClick." Also, be sure to include the parenthesis () when you're invoking a method. Don't confuse methods (which end with ( and )) with attributes and properties which do not end with ( and ).

```
// Using jQuery - Which you tagged...
$("#proxyAnchor").attr("href", proxyImgSrc).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're after:

```
var proxyImgSrc="CostMetrics.aspx?Model=" + model +"&KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=410&width=650";
$("#proxyAnchor").attr('href', proxyImgSrc).trigger("click");;
```

Answer (score 1):

For an immediate page change, you can also do this:

```
var proxyImgSrc= "CostMetrics.aspx?Model=" + model + "&KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=410&width=650";
window.location = proxyImgSrc;
```

Here's an example from W3 Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_location

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for support of IE, then this example below may help:

suppose you have the blob document in response object:

```
                 var blob = new Blob([response.responseText], { type: headers['content-type'] });
            if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                //Launches the associated application for a File or Blob saving for non webkit based browser such as safari or IE
                navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "cvSummary.xml");
            }
            else {
                //code for webkit based browser
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.style = "display: none";
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = "cvSummary.xml";
                link.dataset.downloadurl = ["text/xml", link.download, link.href].join(':');
                link.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }
```