# How can I simulate a click to an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to simulate a click to an anchor tag with all extras like correct target handling.

There seems to be a "[click()][3]" method for anchor's DOM object but not all browsers support that. Firefox throws this error:

> Error: anchorObj.click is not a function

It also works strangely on Opera 10 and Konqueror, causing infinite clicks to happen when it's called inside onclick handler of a surrounding div. I guess only IE8 works fine with it. Anyway I don't want it since major browsers mostly have problems with it.

I found this alternate solution for Firefox in Mozilla forums:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null); 
anchorObj.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

This seems too ugly and cumbersome for me. I don't know how compatible it is and I want to avoid writing browser specific code as much as possible.

I can't use location.href = anchorObj.href; because it doesn't handle "target" attribute. I can do some hard coding based on target's value but I'd like to avoid that as well.

There is suggestion of switching to JQuery but I'm not sure how well it handles target property either since I haven't worked with it before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Invoking click-event of an anchor tag from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980709/javascript-invoking-click-event-of-an-anchor-tag-from-javascript)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Here is a complete test case that simulates the `click` event, calls all handlers attached (however they have been attached), maintains the `"target"` attribute (`"srcElement"` in IE), bubbles like a normal event would, and emulates IE's recursion-prevention. Tested in FF 2, Chrome 2.0, Opera 9.10 and of course IE (6):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>
function fakeClick(event, anchorObj) {
  if (anchorObj.click) {
    anchorObj.click()
  } else if(document.createEvent) {
    if(event.target !== anchorObj) {
      var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
      evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null); 
      var allowDefault = anchorObj.dispatchEvent(evt);
      // you can check allowDefault for false to see if
      // any handler called evt.preventDefault().
      // Firefox will *not* redirect to anchorObj.href
      // for you. However every other browser will.
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div onclick="alert('Container clicked')">
  <a id="link" href="#" onclick="alert((event.target || event.srcElement).innerHTML)">Normal link</a>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="fakeClick(event, document.getElementById('link'))">
  Fake Click on Normal Link
</button>

<br /><br />

<div onclick="alert('Container clicked')">
    <div onclick="fakeClick(event, this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0])"><a id="link2" href="#" onclick="alert('foo')">Embedded Link</a></div>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="fakeClick(event, document.getElementById('link2'))">Fake Click on Embedded Link</button>

</body>
</html>
```

[Demo here.](http://jsbin.com/iyadi)

It avoids recursion in non-IE browsers by inspecting the event object that is initiating the simulated click, by inspecting the `target` attribute of the event (which [remains unchanged during propagation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling)).

Obviously IE does this internally holding a reference to its [global `event` object](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling). DOM level 2 defines no such global variable, so for that reason the simulator must pass in its local copy of `event`.

Comment: An update: as of now initMouseEvent is deprecated see  [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent) use custom events instead [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Answer (score 11):

Quoted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click

> The click method is intended to be used with INPUT elements of type button, checkbox, radio, reset or submit. Gecko does not implement the click method on other elements that might be expected to respond to mouse–clicks such as links (A elements), nor will it necessarily fire the click event of other elements.
>
> Non–Gecko DOMs may behave differently.

Unfortunately it sounds like you have already discovered the best solution to your problem.

As a side note, I agree that your solution seems less than ideal, but if you encapsulate the functionality inside a method (much like JQuery would do) it is not so bad.

Answer (score 11):

There is a simpler way to achieve it,

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://getbootstrap.com/" id="fooLinkID" target="_blank">Bootstrap is life !</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Simulating click after 3 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('fooLinkID').click();
}, 3 * 1000);
```

Using plain javascript to simulate a click along with addressing the target property.

You can check working example here on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/senutf6h/).

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Expecting to see a new browser window launched on timeout, but get nothing.

Comment: @TSmith, With just HTML you can't do this, read more here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939928/make-a-link-open-a-new-window-not-tab)

Answer (score 9):

well, you can very quickly test the click dispatch via jQuery like so

```
$('#link-id').click();
```

If you're still having problem with click respecting the target, you can always do this

```
$('#link-id').click( function( event, anchor )
{
  window.open( anchor.href, anchor.target, '' );
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions address the generic intention of the original request. What if we don't know the id of the anchor? What if it doesn't have an id? What if it doesn't even have an href parameter (e.g. prev/next icon in a carousel)? What if we want to apply the action to multiple anchors with different models in an agnostic fashion? Here's an example that does something instead of a click, then later simulates the click (for any anchor or other tag):

```
var clicker = null;
$('a').click(function(e){ 
    clicker=$(this); // capture the clicked dom object
    /* ... do something ... */
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent original click action
});
clicker[0].click(); // this repeats the original click. [0] is necessary.
```