# Sending click event to parent anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I send a click event (JS or JQuery) to a parent object that is an anchor?  My basic HTML looks like:

```
<a href="javascript:myFunc(1,2,3)">
  <img id="btn1" src="myimg.png">
</a>
```

So I can easily reference the anchor through button via:

```
document.getElementById('btn1').parentNode
```

However,

```
document.getElementById('btn1').parentNode.click
```

while it doesn't seem to raise an error in the console on firebug, the javascript function doesn't seem to be firing either.  How do I send a click to this thing.  By the way, I don't have control of the HTML so I can't just ad an ID to the anchor tag.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a tested-solution.

Answer (score 4):

Gone are the days when it's okay to use the `href="javascript:blah"`, especially if you're using a library like jQuery, Dojo, ExtJs or the rest.  Event handlers should always be attached outside of the HTML.

```
$(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().click();
    };
});
```

Here is a snippet that you can test on SO pages (copy+paste into Firebug)

```
$("#hlogo a").click(function() {
    alert("a!");
    return false;
});

$("#hlogo a img").click(function() {
    alert("img!");
    $(this).parent().click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Normal Links with Normal HREF's

```
// assuming the link is always the immediate parent of #btn1
$("#btn1").parent().trigger("click");
```

#### Links with Javascript-Commands as HREF's

I note in your case though that your HREF value is a call to a javascript function, with parameters. For this, you may want to evaluate that HREF, rather than click the link:

```
// run the href-javascript from the parent anchor
eval($("#btn1").parent().attr("href"));
```

I've built a test-case and used firebug to try both methods. The first returns `1`, showing the link was clicked, but the javascript is never executed. The second method actually executes the javascript found within the HREF value of the link itself. This should be an adequate solution to your specific need.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work...is there a way to do this directly through JS?

Comment: Perhaps you need to eval() the href-value, since you're dealing with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: ignore this answer as it's no good for links; see the comments below.**

The `click` property of an `a` element is a function property, aka a method; all you are doing is referencing the property, not invoking it.

```
document.getElementById('btn1').parentNode.click();
```

(note the `()` to cause the method to be invoked) should do it, though if you are using jQuery already then [Jonathan Sampson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841441/sending-click-event-to-parent-anchor/1841454#1841454) will do what you need - there's no point in loading the library and then not using it :-)

Although Jonathan's answer can be shortened, as [jQuery provides a `click` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click):

```
$("#btn1").parent().click();
```

Comment: The `click` property of an `a` element is also an IE proprietary function. It is only standardized for `<input />` elements of type `"button"`, `"checkbox"`, `"radio"`, `"reset"`, or `"submit"`: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-6043025

Comment: Indeed, I stand corrected: furthermore looking through the jQuery code it appears to use `elem["on"+type].apply( elem, data )` for clicks on links, which will invoke an event handler, but won't fire the browser's native link action, I believe.

Comment: Oh, and jQuery's `click` method just calls `trigger`.

Comment: @NickFitz: yep, exactly. jQuery doesn't rely on the `click()` method of `<a>` elements, because the `click()` method of `<a>` elements is unreliable ;) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag/1421968#1421968

Answer (score 0):

jQuery way maybe like this:

```
$(event.target).closest('a').trigger('click')
```

or in your words something like this

```
$('#bth1').closest('a').trigger('click')
```