# How to simulate a click with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering how I can use JavaScript to simulate a click on an element.

Currently I have:

```js
function simulateClick(control) {
  if (document.all) {
    control.click();
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evObj.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 12, 345, 7, 220, false, false, true, false, 0, null );
    control.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="mytest1">test 1</a><br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    simulateClick(document.getElementById('mytest1'));
</script>
```

But it's not working :(

Any ideas?

Comment: "Five Most Common Coding Errors":
http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/worst_4.htm - Just about no one runs IE4 any more and so support for the document.all
 DOM is no longer required. It is really surprising though how many people still use it in their coding. Worse is that support for the
 document.all DOM is often tested for
 in order to determine the browser
 being used and if it is supported then
 the code assumes that the browser is
 Internet Explorer (which is completely
 wrong usage since **Opera** also
 recognises that DOM).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag

Comment: The problem with most of these solutions is that the element being click won't be focused as it normally would had a user clicked it with their cursor. But simply adding element.focus() would fix that.

Comment: @zaf that link is down and will go to a 404 now, but the wayback is here. The article in question is very good. 

https://web.archive.org/web/20150906012912/http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/worst_4.htm

Answer (score 525, accepted):

[**Edit 2022**] The answer was really outdated. Modernized it. The original answer is at the bottom.

Use [`element.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) with a freshly created [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) of the desired type.

Here's an example using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

Fork [this stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pcj3py?file=index.js) to play around with it.

```js
// Note: {bubbles: true} because of the event delegation ...
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
document.addEventListener(`virtualhover`, handle);

// the actual 'trigger' function
const trigger = (el, etype, custom) => {
  const evt = custom ?? new Event( etype, { bubbles: true } );
  el.dispatchEvent( evt );
};

// a custom event ;)
const vHover = new CustomEvent(`virtualhover`, 
  { bubbles: true, detail: `red` });


setTimeout( _ => 
  trigger( document.querySelector(`#testMe`), `click` ), 1000 );

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === `clickTrigger`) {
    trigger(document.querySelector(`#testMe`), `click`);  
  }
  
  if (evt.type === `virtualhover`) {
    evt.target.style.color = evt.detail;
    return setTimeout( _ => evt.target.style.color = ``, 1000 );
  }
  
  if (evt.target.id === `testMe`) {
    document.querySelector(`#testMeResult`)
      .insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, `<p>One of us clicked #testMe. 
        It was <i>${evt.isTrusted ? `<b>you</b>` : `me`}</i>.</p>`);
    trigger(
      document.querySelector(`#testMeResult p:last-child`), 
      `virtualhover`, 
      vHover );  
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 1.2rem/1.5rem verdana, arial;
  margin: 2rem;
}

#testMe {
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  margin: 0.2rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="testMe">
  Test me can be clicked
</div>

<p><button id='clickTrigger'>Click #testMe</button></p>

<div id="testMeResult"></div>
```

**The old answer**:

> Here's what I cooked up. It's pretty simple, but it works:
>
> ```
> function eventFire(el, etype){
>   if (el.fireEvent) {
>     el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
>   } else {
>     var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
>     evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
>     el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this function on a web page (since it's being shown out of context). Can you post an example usage?

Comment: @Anderson Green: I have added an example to this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/W4BHD/

Comment: Proof that this works (in Chromium): +1 with `document.querySelector('[value="2706236"]').nextSibling.nextSibling.dispatchEvent(ev);` :)

Comment: [`fireEvent` is a host object's method in the MSHTML DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536423(v=vs.85).aspx), though, so the usual caveats apply (do not use type-converting tests, but something along [`isHostMethod()`](http://PointedEars.de/wsvn/JSX/trunk/object.js) instead).

Comment: Can anyone, please, explain (or better write a code) how this answer is applied in the OP's original code posted in his question? Where does the control (the button) get specified?

Comment: @KooiInc - WOW!!! **KooiInc**, thank you so much! Yes, I think now I can gasp it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well I tried your java-script on the vote up button :) (worked of-course)

Comment: Chrome: A DOM event generated from JavaScript has triggered a default action inside the browser. This behavior is non-standard and will be removed in M53, around September 2016. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832 for more details.

Comment: To simulate exact user behavior, you should wrap the `dispatchEvent` or `click` invocations with `setTimeout`, as it appears that `dispatchEvent` is [synchronous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22924862/3952799).

Comment: ^^ This can have some implications e.g in the case that you simulate user clicks in your tests, and the click event handler performs some async logic.

Comment: Does this work on older mobile devices?  I've heard old versions of android don't support `myElement.click();`.  Anyway does this work in all browsers?

Comment: This worked for me BUT I had to do an extra step : let's say the link element is in the variable 'a', I had to do `eventFire(a, 'mouseover'); eventFire(a, 'click');` as a security prevented the click to work without an onmouseover before.

Comment: `Event.initEvent` is now **deprecated** https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent

Comment: @PointedEars I think this is a bit better form for your upvote thing: `document.querySelector('[value="2706236"]').nextSibling.nextSibling.click()`

Comment: @AlfredoGallegos In which way is that “a bit better”?

Comment: If somebody tried to run your snippet without the same context as the post above with the ev event, the code will not work. It's a bit cleaner and more legible to just do `.click()` :)

Comment: @AlfredoGallegos You are not making sense. Have you even read the question and the answer in which context I made my *comment*? Also, while `.click()` might be more _readable_, it is _not_ “a bit cleaner”. To begin with, [`.click()` was *proprietary* before HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-48250443).

Comment: Can you explain the "if" statement? What is it for?

Comment: see the below answer.  .click() works all the way back to IE 6 (without jQuery)

Comment: just remove this as the answer already - it's ridiculous to keep an answer like this when the clear answers are below. NO-ONE is going to use this answer when they can simply... $("#mytest1").click();

Comment: Weird how the "<b>you</b>" branch never fires though. What's the deal with that?

Comment: @Hakanai What makes you think it *should* fire?

Comment: @KooiInc the branch exists in the code.

Comment: I made it easier to figure out what was meant to happen. https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rf8tyr

Comment: @Hakanai  `<b>`-elements are *not* handled in the snippet, but of course you can create  custom handlers for that too. Maybe this [stackblitz fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7ovfb6?file=index.js) clarifies it somewhat more.

Answer (score 641):

What about something simple like:

```
document.getElementById('elementID').click();
```

[Supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) even by IE.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson Yes it works perfectly in IE - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The question was "does it work in ie as well?" -  the answer is yes - AFAIK at least down to 8, haven't checked 7

Comment: Did this not exist before? Why did the 2010 answers not mention this simple solution? Just curious...

Comment: It is not recent, but it doesn't work on very old Firefox versions (before Firefox 5). Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: @NinoŠkopac Works great currently for desktop but no guarantee to work with mobile browsers. Even the mozilla developer site doesn't show mobile support.

Comment: May help someone: when using this to 'click' an faq item linked to in the url (e.g. /faq#item-1), I needed to use: setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById(hash).click();
    }, 300);

Comment: @Parth Maybe it did, it just didn't *click* for them.

Comment: The only thing is don't try to replace getElementById with querySelector it is not the same.

Comment: @RahulSonwanshi just tried `document.querySelector('#auth_modal .close').click()` on my website and it worked just fine

Comment: It doesn't work for me in Chrome. If I have an element and I do `.click`, the browser console tells me that this is a function. If I do `.click()` with parenthesis then it returns undefined and nothing is clicked on the page.

Comment: @AaronFranke Interesting. I tried Chrome on my use case and `.click()` seemed fine. Same with mobile chrome. I was using it on a radio button label.

Comment: Isn't working in Chrome.

Answer (score 85):

Have you considered using jQuery to avoid all the browser detection?  With jQuery, it would be as simple as:

```
$("#mytest1").click();
```

Comment: This only fire jQuery event handlers, not the default behavior (browser goes to href in that case)

Comment: I don't know about sad but it sure can be convenient to not have to keep recoding the same browser detection routines time and again.

Comment: @ErikAigner: I was wondering the same, but glad that the accepted answer in this case is plain JavaScript and not jQuery. Seen that too many times on SO. Once more: jQuery is JavaScript, but JavaScript is not jQuery. Although I like to use jQuery, I'm seeing more and more that devs don't understand the real plain thing. My 2 cents, couldn't resist to comment. ;)

Comment: There are also a lot of humans that wouldn't know where to start if they had to wash their clothes by hand, since the majority of households own a washer, and almost as many have a clothes dryer. jQuery, much like modern appliances, have made an old chore much easier and less error prone. It's not the solution for everyone, however, downvoting an answer that accurately answers the question using more concise, understandable syntax while being cross-browser compatible seems backwards. +1.

Comment: There is nothing sad about choosing the easiest way. In this case however, the answer was not appropriate and should get removed.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Then you also shouldn't walk anywhere since driving is so much easier. But we know that's silly. You walk if you don't need to go far. You use plain JavaScript if you need to do something simple and don't want to load an entire library to do it. No need to waste gas/bandwitdth for something simple.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer But is `$("#mytest1").click();` "more concise, understandable syntax" than `document.getElementById('mytest1').click();`?

Comment: @Jacob Yes but now we have electric scooters so then why not use javascript (Being walking) and then have flying cars (Being Python). Because the road (Being HTML) is like a river (The river of course being the internet). When you finally hit a deer (Console Errors) you may not know how to fix it so you use a mechanic (Stack Overflow). Do you follow.

Answer (score 31):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('mytest1');

// Simulate clicking on the specified element.
triggerEvent( elem, 'click' );

/**
 * Trigger the specified event on the specified element.
 * @param  {Object} elem  the target element.
 * @param  {String} event the type of the event (e.g. 'click').
 */
function triggerEvent( elem, event ) {
  var clickEvent = new Event( event ); // Create the event.
  elem.dispatchEvent( clickEvent );    // Dispatch the event.
}
```

### Reference

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events
- https://codepen.io/felquis/pen/damDA

Comment: I believe this should be the best answer nowadays

Comment: Nowadays it's easier to simply do `element.click();`. Most major browsers support this. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25806894/470749 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2381612/470749

Comment: This is the answer that works for me, It triggers a click event like the way a user click on a browser, not calling an onclick event on the target like `element.click();` 

Answer (score 15):

You could save yourself a bunch of space by using jQuery. You only need to use:

```
$('#myElement').trigger("click")
```

Comment: OP asked for JavaScript. Although this is compact and functional, some people prefer no-Library JS over things like jQuery.

Comment: Save space by downloading jquery?

Comment: @MH I think a more valid argument would be "to keep it simple". Your default profile here in SO is about the same size of jQuery.

Answer (score 10):

In javascript grab element by its id or class name and then apply `.click()` to make click happens
like:

```
document.getElementById("btnHandler").click();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bad bot!  Simplest, fastest, working solution.

Answer (score 8):

The top answer is the best! However, it was not triggering mouse events for me in Firefox when `etype = 'click'`.

So, I changed the `document.createEvent` to `'MouseEvents'` and that fixed the problem. The extra code is to test whether or not another bit of code was interfering with the event, and if it was cancelled I would log that to console.

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    var canceled = !el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    if (canceled) {
      // A handler called preventDefault.
      console.log("automatic click canceled");
    } else {
      // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simulating an event is similar to creating a custom event. To simulate a mouse event

- we gonna have to create `MouseEvent` using `document.createEvent()`.
- Then using `initMouseEvent()`, we've to set up the mouse event that is going to occur.
- Then dispatched the mouse event on the element on which you'd like to simulate an event.

In the following code, I've used `setTimeout` so that the button gets clicked automatically after 1 second.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Simulated click');
});

const simulatedDivClick = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');

simulatedDivClick.initEvent(
  'click', /* Event type */
  true, /* bubbles */
  true, /* cancelable */
  document.defaultView, /* view */
  0, /* detail */
  0, /* screenx */
  0, /* screeny */
  0, /* clientx */
  0, /* clienty */
  false, /* ctrlKey */
  false, /* altKey */
  false, /* shiftKey */
  0, /* metaKey */
  null, /* button */
  null /* relatedTarget */
);

// Automatically click after 1 second
setTimeout(function() {
  div.dispatchEvent(simulatedDivClick);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div> Automatically click </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById('elementId').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click",{bubbles: true, cancellable: true}));
```

Follow this link to know about the mouse events using Javascript and browser compatibility for the same

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("element").click()
```

Simply select the element from the DOM. The node has a click function, which you can call.

Or

```
document.querySelector("#element").click()
```

Comment: I know. I was in a rush so I did not add an explanation. Sorry about that.

Comment: You don't use a `#` when you're getting an element by id. If you want to do that, use query selector, i.e. `document.querySelector('#elment').click();`.

Comment: Oops made another typo

Comment: Clear concise answer

Answer (score 2):

Honestly none of the answers here worked for my specific case. jquery was out of the question so all those answers are untested. I will say I built this answer up from @mnishiguchi answer above but this was the only thing that actually ended up working.

```js
// select the element by finding the id of mytest1
const el = document.querySelector('#mytest1');

// pass the element to the simulateClick function
simulateClick( el );

function simulateClick(element){
    trigger( element, 'mousedown' );
    trigger( element, 'click' );
    trigger( element, 'mouseup' );

    function trigger( elem, event ) {
      elem.dispatchEvent( new MouseEvent( event ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use timeout if the event is not getting triggered

```
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('your_id').click(); }, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

This question seems an XY problem. You wanted to simulate a click on an anchor element to load a link, but you can load the link without clicking the anchor element.

```js
const url = document.querySelector("#mytest1").getAttribute("href");
window.location.assign(url);
```

See [location: assign() method - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very well documented, but we can trigger any kinds of events very simply.

This example will trigger 50 double click on the button:

```js
let theclick = new Event("dblclick")

for (let i = 0;i < 50;i++){
  action.dispatchEvent(theclick) 
}
```

```html
<button id="action" ondblclick="out.innerHTML+='Wtf '">TEST</button>
<div id="out"></div>
```

> *The Event interface represents an event which takes place in the DOM.*
>
> *An event can be triggered by the user action e.g. clicking the mouse
> button or tapping keyboard, or generated by APIs to represent the
> progress of an asynchronous task. It can also be triggered
> programmatically, such as by calling the HTMLElement.click() method of
> an element, **or by defining the event, then sending it to a specified
> target using EventTarget.dispatchEvent().***
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me....
Click event can be called on clicking the button or do it from JavaScript file.
In this code either click on the button to show alert or simply call it on some condition or without condition

```js
    function ss(){
    alert('dddddddddddddddddddddddd');
    }
    var mybtn=document.getElementById('btn');
    mybtn.click();
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <button id="btn" onclick="ss()">click to see </button>
    </body>
    </html>
```