# Convert function from jQuery("#page>ul>li:last>a").click() to Prototype

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I have a statement using jQuery as below:

```
jQuery("#page>ul>li:last>a").click();
```

How can I do that in Prototype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector is the same in prototype as it is in jQuery. The difference is you have to use the `$$` function in prototype and then iterate over each selected element :

```
$$("#page > ul > li:last > a").each(function(element) {
    eventFire(element, "click");
});
```

Looks like prototype does not have a method like jQuery's [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger). You can write a function like the one found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/simulate-click-javascript):

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I use your way with the below, I will have:
$$("#list > ul > li:last > a").each(function(element) {
    element.on('click',function(e){
        //alert(e);
    });
});

Comment: So, my question is, can I do that? Or something is wrong here?

Comment: @vietean: The jQuery code you posted does not bind an event handler to the click event: it *triggers* the click event on the selected elements.

Comment: how can I understand between trigger and event?

Comment: aha, I have read your link, and now I got it. Thanks. Love your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$$('#page>ul>li:last>a')[0].on('click',function(event){

 });
```

Comment: The end call in the OPs post does not create a handler, it triggers the event.

Comment: Additionally, the selector could return more than one `a`

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker, yes, you are right, then http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/each

Comment: it is fine for me (Prototype 1.7), on Firefox