# Inconsistencies with prop('checked') when clicked manually or programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am having an issue with `jQuery 1.7.2/1.8.2` (didn't test earlier versions) whereby `prop('checked')` seems to be returning inconsistent values.

I have 2 unchecked checkboxes:

```
<input id="input1" type="checkbox"/>
<input id="input2" type="checkbox"/>​
```

When I call `$('#input1').click()` on `ready`, `prop('checked')` gives me `false`. When I click manually on `#input2` I get `true`. [I've created a `jsFiddle` showing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/eza2Y/3/).

I would expect the `prop('checked')` method to return data in a consistent fashion inside the `click` event handler, no matter how this was triggered, which doesn't seem to be the case.

**Am I missing something? Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround available to have consistent `.prop('checked')` data inside the `click` handler no matter how this was triggered?**

PS: I've tested with `FF 15.0.1`, `Chrome 21.0.1180`, `jQuery 1.7.2 and 1.8.2`. Issue is the same whether I use `.click(` or `.on('click'`

Comment: You can refer following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/simulate-click-javascript to simulate any JavaScript event

Comment: I tried to use the function from the accepted answer from in link you shared, but it doesn't help: http://jsfiddle.net/eza2Y/12/, any idea why?

Comment: it is working check console but you have to set checked = true $('#input1')[0].checked = true; updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eza2Y/19/.

Comment: update jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eza2Y/21/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the inconsistent behaviour is the difference between `.click()` and actually clicking the element. Actually clicking it changes the `checked` state, whereas `.click()` merely executes the jQuery-bound handlers.

So clicking the element changes whether it is checked or not, then tells you the new state, whereas using the trigger mechanism only tells you the previously existing state.