# How do you trigger an ‘isTrusted=true’ click event using JavaScript in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm trying to impersonate user clicks and mouse movements using a Chrome extension.

For example:
In my content script there is a button click.

```js
document.querySelector("SOME_SELECTOR").click();
```

This line triggers a click event with the following property:

```
MouseEvent {isTrusted: false}
```

How do you trigger a MouseEvent where the isTrusted property will be true?

Answer (score 21):

You can inject trusted events using the debugger interface.

```
chrome.debugger.attach(target, "1.2", function() {
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand(target, "Input.dispatchMouseEvent", arguments)
})
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-2/Input

Comment: Great! This also works for sending trusted key events via `Input.dispatchKeyEvent`.

Comment: How do I implement that on background script for Chrome extension?

Comment: @diofeher, here's a working implementation: https://github.com/Sentero-esp12/IsTrusted-event-Debugger-API

Comment: one question.. where do you execute this `chrome.debugger` since I'm not seeing it when I open console

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is possible, since it's a read-only property that signifies exactly what you're trying to fake, namely if the event originated from the end user or from a script.
There used to be browser-based differences, (IE used to have all events as trusted) but I don't know if this is still the case.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

There may still be ways around this, as mentioned for firefox in this topic:[Are events generated by Firefox extension 'trusted'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456705/are-events-generated-by-firefox-extension-trusted)

But you'll have to have a look at the chrome documentation to check if they have similar methods of delegating an event back to the window, since it does mention extension events are/can become trusted in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code. The isTrusted event will be true.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {
    if (tab.url.indexOf("instagram") != -1) {
    chrome.debugger.attach( {tabId: tab.id}, "1.2", async function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
        //opts = {type: "mousePressed", button: "left", x: 557, y: 204, clickCount: 1};
        //chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId: tab.id}, "Input.dispatchMouseEvent", opts);
        //opts0 = {type: "mouseReleased", button: "left", x: 557, y: 204, clickCount: 1};
        //chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId: tab.id}, "Input.dispatchMouseEvent", opts0);

        opts1 = {type: "keyDown", code: "KeyA", key: "a", text: "a"}
        chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId: tab.id}, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", opts1);
        chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId: tab.id}, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", {type: "keyDown", code: "KeyB", key: "b", text: "b"});

        //opts2 = {type: "keyUp", code: "KeyA", key: "a"}
        //chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId: tab.id}, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", opts2);
    }, 5000);

    })
}
  
}});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).