# Chrome extension debugger undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to simulate a trusted click event for a chrome extension using the debugger api seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853588/how-to-trigger-an-istrusted-true-click-event-using-javascript).

However, chrome.debugger is undefined.

```
chrome.debugger.attach(target, "1.2", function() {
    chrome.debugger.sendCommand(target, "Input.dispatchMouseEvent", arguments)
})
```

manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    "debugger", "storage"
 ]
```

Am I missing something? How can I effectively call chrome.debugger? When I look at the permissions in chrome://extensions it shows that I have "Access the page debugger backend"

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) my guess would be you're doing it in a content script, which have access only to a few basic API, or you've set a breakpoint in devtools (or used a `debugger` statement) prior to the first access to any `chrome` API (this is a known bug in Chrome).

Comment: where can you use it if not in a content script? background? @wOxxOm

Comment: In any extension page, including the background page, of course.

Comment: @wOxxOm got it, thanks. can i call bind onClick events to html elements on specific pages from a background script/?

Comment: No, declaring a background script creates a separate hidden background page where that script(s) run. To access the web page DOM from browser tabs you need a content script. See also [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)

Comment: thanks. one last questions since you seem knowledgeable. ideas on how to make a trusted event for a browser extension? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853588/how-to-trigger-an-istrusted-true-click-event-using-javascript)

Comment: The thread you've linked contains an answer. Be more specific or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the debugger interface to the tab via a background script:

```
let tabId = tab.id;
let debuggeeId = { tabId };
chrome.debugger.attach(debuggeeId, version, onAttach.bind(null, debuggeeId));
```

And then

```
const onDebuggerEnabled = (debuggeeId) => {
  debuggerEnabled = true
}

const onAttach = (debuggeeId) => {
chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
    debuggeeId, "Debugger.enable", {},
    onDebuggerEnabled.bind(null, debuggeeId));
}
```

Then you can use message passing to send requests to the background script from the content script: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

And

```
if (debuggerEnabled) {
chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, "Input.dispatchMouseEvent", { type: "mousePressed", x: xC, y: yC, button: "left" }, function (e) { console.log('mousedown', e) });

chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debuggeeId, "Input.dispatchMouseEvent", { type: "mouseReleased", x: xC, y: yC, button: "left" }, function (e) { console.log('mouseup', e) });
} 
// xC, yC are your coordinates
```

This is a working example: https://github.com/Sentero-esp12/IsTrusted-event-Debugger-API