# KEYPRESS Function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-manipulation

I am trying to make a chrome extension for Google Meet, in which when I press the space bar, the mic should turn on and vice-versa. This is my code...

```
//Listening to key events to trigger suitable event
document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
        items = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].hasAttribute("aria-label")) {
                if (items[i].getAttribute("aria-label")
                    .includes("microphone")) {
                    items[i].click();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I press the space bar, the microphone does not get affected, on the other hand, if I add an alert, that works perfectly fine. What could be the mistake? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is "items" inside for loop?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the variable declaration. Items is the variable holding all the "div" elememts on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to guess without looking at the source code for Google Meet, I would assume it was because of the `isTrusted` property of the event that you are trying to simulate.

I was defeated by this a while back, but my understanding of it is that when the event is fired by a user, `event.isTrusted` is `true`, but when it's fired by a script `event.isTrusted` is `false`

Somewhere in the source code of Google Meet, there is most likely an `if` statement checking to see if this property is true. For example:

```js
if (event.isTrusted) {
  //toggle microphone
}
```

The most likely reason this is in place is so if a virus got on a user's computer it wouldn't easily be able to toggle their microphone.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but is there any possible way to override that?!

Comment: maybe check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853588/how-to-trigger-an-istrusted-true-click-event-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @c1uq92, It was of great help :)