# Perform isTrusted:true event in browser

Tags: javascript, events, browser, frontend, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to figure out a way to perform a trusted event programmatically in the browser.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

I know it says it's a readonly event but I figure there must be some sort of work around if the user really wants it. After all the browser/frontend is entirely client side so you should be able to manipulate it yourself if you so choose (via some option in the browser etc)

I came across this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53488689/3097821 but I can't figure out to to implement it.

It can either be a click or a keyboard event.

Can anybody help me out on this?

Comment: The answer you found is for a *chrome extension*. Alternatively, you can use any third-party tool to control your browser via [CDP](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol) and send the same command Input.dispatchMouseEvent.

Comment: @wOxxOm doing this via extension would be an acceptable usecase. Thanks! I'll look into it. If you can provide a working example as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Try adapting [this official sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/mv2-archive/api/debugger/pause-resume).

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh man, thank you so much.  Really appreciate it. Will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web content cannot generate a trusted event under any circumstances -- that is the whole point. Some actions don't care if an event is trusted or not (clicking a link, for example), but some do need to distinguish between a legitimate user-triggered event and a synthetic one create by untrusted web content.

Web Extensions are assumed to be working on the user's behalf, so they are allowed to create trusted events.