# PhantomJS click a link on a page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have written some parts of a PhantomJS application. I am parsing on a website where I am writing username and password to a formular. After this I have to click on a link. Whereas I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'myLink.click()')

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():11
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():22
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():22
```

This is my PhantomJS code:

```
if(document.getElementById("m_Content_submitbtn2").getAttribute('data-role') == "button"){
        var myLink = document.getElementById("m_Content_submitbtn2");   
    myLink.click();
}
```

And this is my link:

```
<div class='button'><a href="#" data-role="button" tabindex='0' onclick='WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;m$Content$submitbtn2&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true)); return false;' id="m_Content_submitbtn2">Log ind</a></div>&nbsp;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhantomJS; click an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element)

Answer (score 6):

You are attempting to use the `click()` method on an `<a>` element which is not supported in all browser by default. Instead try using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706236/684353) where instead of `myLink.click();` you will have to do `eventFire(myLink, 'click');`.

Comment: This just gives me: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: eventFire

Comment: Didn't see there was a link there. Sorry.

Comment: help.  trying to use this in phantomjs and getting reference error no matter what.

Answer (score 3):

Or include jQuery and do something like:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.sample.com', function() {
  page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
      $("button").click();
    });
    phantom.exit()
  });
});
```

Comment: `page.includeJS` works properly, but I get a `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $` after that.

Comment: ...ok I need to switch to `document` page context with `page.evaluate` anyways. At that point it get the `$` but navigation does not occur  - I don't get the callback in `onNavigationRequested`