# PhantomJS; click an element

Tags: javascript, click, phantomjs

How do I click an element in PhantomJS?

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    document.getElementById('idButtonSpan').click();  
});
```

This gives me an error "undefined is not a function..."

If I instead

```
 return document.getElementById('idButtonSpan');
```

and then print it,

then it prints [object object], so the element does exist.

The element acts as a button, but it's actually just a span element, not a submit input.

I was able to get this button click to work with Casper, but Casper had other limitations so I'm back to PhantomJS.

Comment: Time to accept an answer.

Comment: There are 3 answers that use the "dispatchEvent" function, 2 that use "sendEvent", one that is practically useless and one that should be a comment.

Comment: Don't forget the # sign...

Comment: Why has no one yet pointed out that `click()` does not exist in DOM API at all, you probably saw it in jQuery or some lib like that?

Comment: 4 years later: Answer accepted! I got away from PhantomJS so couldn't verify the answer. But I'll accept that 58 upvotes are correct :) @torazaburo

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`.click()` is not standard. You need to create an event and dispatch it:

```
function click(el){
    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    ev.initMouseEvent(
        "click",
        true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
        window, null,
        0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
        false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
        0 /*left*/, null
    );
    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: Wrapping `el` with jQuery gives you this defn of click. It'll work in your browser and in Phantom. `$(el).click()`

Comment: omg tears of joy, after almost 12 hours of continuous struggle with this! sniff sniff!

Comment: Worked fine for me too, but one must remember not to exit PhantomJS too soon, before the processing is finished. I needed a short script to just click one button and exit. This would not work for me until I called phantom.exit() from within page.onLoadFinished = function() {...};

Comment: document.querySelector(element).click() works just fine for me.

Comment: To work with custom controls, I had to make more complicated solution with 3 events:

function triggerMouseEvent(elm, eventType) {
    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    ev.initMouseEvent(
        eventType,
        true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
        window, null,
        0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
        false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
        0 /*left*/, null
    );
    elm.dispatchEvent(ev);
}

function click(elm) {
    triggerMouseEvent(elm, 'mousedown');
    triggerMouseEvent(elm, 'mouseup');
    triggerMouseEvent(elm, 'click');
}

Comment: This does not work for me. Could someone take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560375/why-does-the-button-click-not-happen-phantomjs and point out if I missed something?

Answer (score 34):

Alternatively to @torazaburo's response, you could stub `HTMLElement.prototype.click` when running in PhantomJS. For example, we use PhantomJS + QUnit to run our tests and in our `qunit-config.js` we have something like this:

```
if (window._phantom) {
  // Patch since PhantomJS does not implement click() on HTMLElement. In some 
  // cases we need to execute the native click on an element. However, jQuery's 
  // $.fn.click() does not dispatch to the native function on <a> elements, so we
  // can't use it in our implementations: $el[0].click() to correctly dispatch.
  if (!HTMLElement.prototype.click) {
    HTMLElement.prototype.click = function() {
      var ev = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
      ev.initMouseEvent(
          'click',
          /*bubble*/true, /*cancelable*/true,
          window, null,
          0, 0, 0, 0, /*coordinates*/
          false, false, false, false, /*modifier keys*/
          0/*button=left*/, null
      );
      this.dispatchEvent(ev);
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: A heads up that I'm running Karma 0.12.17 with PhantomJs 1.9.7-14. There is no `window._phantom` object so I just removed that condition and it worked as expected.

Comment: I wonder if the function should accept parameters in order to set different coordinates for the MouseEvent

Answer (score 16):

It's not pretty, but I've been using this to allow me to use jQuery for the selection:

```
var rect = page.evaluate(function() {
    return $('a.whatever')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
});
page.sendEvent('click', rect.left + rect.width / 2, rect.top + rect.height / 2);
```

but you can always replace `$(s)[0]` with `document.querySelector(s)` if not using jQuery.

(It does rely on the element being in view mind, i.e. your viewportSize.height is big enough).

Comment: Tried all possible approaches and this is the only option that worked for me when trying to click on `tr`.

Comment: Worked on phantomjs 1.9.0 and with an <a> element

Comment: the best solution imo, `+1`

Answer (score 8):

Hope the following method will be useful. It worked for me in version 1.9

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    var a = document.getElementById("spr-sign-in-btn-standard");
    var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    e.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
    waitforload = true;
});
```

This worked for me. Hope this will be useful for others also

Comment: @Jobins john whats waitforload = true?

Comment: @QadirHussain Its actually waiting for the page to load completely. Its almost like setting up a particular time to load the page.

Answer (score 6):

With `1.9.2` this worked for me, click handlers were triggered:

```
var a = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelector('a.open');
});

page.sendEvent('click', a.offsetLeft, a.offsetTop);
```

Comment: It's not on all elements. For example <a> does not have it. On buttons it's there.

Answer (score 6):

use simple JavaScript with `evaluate`, something like this:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    document.getElementById('yourId').click();
});
```

Comment: Actually it now IS the correct solution now with PhantomJS 2.x

Answer (score 3):

I never was able to directly click the element. Instead, I looked at the html to find what function was called with onclick, and then called that function.

Comment: how could you find the function and how you call it if it has been attached through addEventListener?

Answer (score 2):

Document.querySelector(element).click() works when using Phantomjs 2.0

```
click: function (selector, options, callback) {
    var self = this;
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    options = options || {timeout:1000}; 
    setTimeout(function () { 
        self.page.evaluate(function(targetSelector) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                document.querySelector(targetSelector).click();
            }) ;
        }, function () {
                deferred.resolve();
        }, selector);
    }, options.timeout);
    return deferred.promise.nodeify(callback);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Double clicks are also possible with PhantomJS.

## Recommended

This is adapted from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026636/1816580) of [stovroz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68602/stovroz) and triggers a native `dblclick` including the `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `click` events (two of each).

```
var rect = page.evaluate(function(selector){
    return document.querySelector(selector).getBoundingClientRect();
}, selector);
page.sendEvent('doubleclick', rect.left + rect.width / 2, rect.top + rect.height / 2);
```

## Other ways

The following two ways only trigger the `dblclick` event, but not the other events that should precede it.

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948355/1816580) of [torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo):

```
page.evaluate(function(selector){
    var el = document.querySelector(sel);
    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    ev.initMouseEvent(
        'dblclick',
        true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
        window, null,
        0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
        false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
        0 /*left*/, null
    );
    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}, selector);
```

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25180804/1816580) of [Jobins John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3431942/jobins-john):

```
page.evaluate(function(selector){
    var el = document.querySelector(sel);
    var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    e.initMouseEvent('dblclick', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    el.dispatchEvent(e);
}, selector);
```

[**Full test script**](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/54f4ab35940170f7449a1cf274c63bec)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is using jQuery.

```
page.evaluate(function() {
  page.includeJs("your_jquery_file.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
      $('button[data-control-name="see_more"]').click();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using JQuery, the JQuery UI created a utility to simulate these: [jquery-simulate](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/jquery-simulate). I use this in PhantomJS and Chrome

```
$ele..simulate( "click" );
```