# Phantomjs page automation getting TypeError: 'null'

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

To test out using JavaScript with PhantomJS I'm trying to write a script that will go to the url "http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html" and then click on the PhantomJS logo bringing the page to the PhantomJS homepage. My goal is to navigate to a url and successfully click on an html element. However I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector('img [alt
="PhantomJS"]').click')

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():3

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():5

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():5
```

Here is my code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html', function(status) {
console.log(status);
page.render('websiteBeforeClick.png');

page.evaluate(function() {
  document.querySelector('img [alt="PhantomJS"]').click();
});    

page.render('websiteAfterClick.png');
phantom.exit();
});
```

Is my css selector incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go on that page and run `document.querySelector('img [alt ="PhantomJS"]')` you'll see that it already returns `null` there.

It's because of the space before the `[` in your selector. Try `document.querySelector('img[alt="PhantomJS"]')`.

That is your first problem. Then you're trying to use `click` but that won't work, you need to  dispatch a click event. See this [other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element) for a solution to that problem.