# how can casperjs click() tag not an anchor

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, casperjs

target html is like

```
<script src="http://static.com/js/qiyi/config.js" type="text/javascript">
<dl class="selected">
   <dt>
       <span data-value="2014">2014年</span>
   </dt>
</dl>
<dl>
   <dt>
      <span data-value="2013">2013年</span>
   </dt>
</dl>
```

is not a simple anchor tag, so in my browser, when i click the span tag, it will call the config.js to do something(i dont know what does it did), it will get change the content. but when i use

```
this.click()
```

to simulate the mouse action, it doesnot work.
because i know the casperjs can work like a browser.
if i want to crawl different years content, how can i do

my code is

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    clientScripts: [
        "jquery-1.7.2.js",
        "config.js"],  //in url page call this js
    remoteScripts: ["http://static.qiyi.com/js/qiyi/config.js"],//also the config.js

    stepTimeout: 120 * 1000,  //单步超时时间
    pageSettings: {  
        loadImages: false  
    },  
    verbose: true,  
    logLevel: "error"  
});   

var fs = require('fs');
var filename = 'content.txt';

casper.on('resource.received', function(resource) {
    casper.echo(resource.url);
});

casper.on('click', function(resource) {
    casper.echo("click");
});

casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

casper.on("resource.error", function(resourceError {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resourceError));});

casper.start("http://www......");
casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function(){
        document.querySelectorAll('[data-value="2013"]')[0].click();
        //it does not work
    });
    this.echo("click");
});
casper.then(function() {
    this.click('span[data-value="2013"]');
    //it does not work
    fs.write(filename, this.getHTML(), 'w');
    this.echo("click");
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: `this` is probably a reference to the Casper object. Where are you calling it from?

Comment: i have edit the question. it does not work. so i suspect the config.js can not in the html by casper

Comment: Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. If bind is an issue, you need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521).

Comment: Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error) to see it is actually the resource error like this: `casper.on("resource.error", function(resourceError){console.log(JSON.stringify(resourceError));});`

Comment: @ArtjomB. thank you for you help, i have update my code, but it still not work, my friend who is familiar with UED, tell me this config.js like a contextual, so i can not simulate that click function, i have learn some knowledge to use crawl, in this case, i have nothing to do, thanks a lot for you help, and i also hope this problem can be solved.

Comment: @ArtjomB. i have update the code, and add some event, in log i found the click has work, and received http://cache.video.qiyi.com/sdvlst/6/1300000224/2013/?cb=scDtVdListC , but i use this.getHTML(), and save it, i still 2014, not 2013

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If this is a production page and the config.js is included in the page, why do you try to include it through casper again? You probably can't overwrite configurations that are done in the original config.js with your own, but that depends on the actual code of config.js. Please some string to distinguish between the events. Also, have you tried waiting a little after the click? `this.wait(5000, function(){fs.write(...);});`

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks a lot for you help. it is worked. because i am a newbie, i am not insure about the page if include in. at present, the casperjs can work like browser, and include all the js environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhantomJS; click an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element)

Comment: @ArtjomB. i have a little confuse, how can i know the exact time that i must wait to get the resource, because you write 5000. is it have any api to know the resource have all get in?

Comment: If the data is loaded as an ajax request, you can specifically wait for this request to finish if you know something about the url. For example: `this.waitForResource(/json/, function(){...});` if it has `json` somewhere inside it by using a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you first use js, you must be sure about how to debug,include page.error and capture event is important.like

```
casper.on("click", function(){this.echo();});
casper.on("page.error", function(){this.echo();});
```

the event happen you can get.
for this problem, after click, must have some time to receive the resource.

```
this.wait(5000, function(){fs.write(...);})
```

thank you @ArtjomB.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to evaluate some javascript (that has access to the window object as if you were in the browser) with `casper.evaluate`

```
casper.evaluate(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-value="2014"]')[0].click();
});
```

Comment: i have try this, it does not work. and i dont know the casper how to work, like <a... it will work, so i suspect the casper cannot make the config.js in the html

Comment: Is the <span> an actual link?

Comment: i do not know about that, when i click <span>, it call the config.js, and the content of html change

Answer (score 0):

Use the clickLabel function, outside of the evaluate function Works for span's in my code

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.clickLabel('2014', 'span');
});
```

[Found here](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#clicklabel)

Comment: thank you for you help, but it doesnot work, maybe the span dont have a href?

Comment: My spans all have hrefs in them which could be the problem you have then

Comment: its mean i have to know how does the config.js work? and simulate? but the config.js have compressed, so i can not know that

Comment: I dont know if this will help much, but online tools exist like [JS NICE](http://www.jsnice.org) to decompress js. Not sure if that will help

Comment: @liubochao988 This cannot work because the text must match perfectly: `clickLabel('2014年', 'span')`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. thank you for help.when i use that, it get error, so i have change 2014年. but i still doesnot work. so i thought the casper cannot load config.js

Comment: Look at adding client scripts [here](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#index-1)