# Cannot click element with Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, click, phantomjs

From post: [How to ng-click an A directive in a PhantomJS test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554797/how-to-ng-click-an-a-directive-in-a-phantomjs-test?lq=1) I understand I need to create my own function to click an element, but how do I use it?

The following code gives me error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'click(obj)')`

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://somesite.com/document.html';

page.open(url, function(status) {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        var obj = document.querySelectorAll('button')[0];
        click(obj);
    });
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});


function click(el){
    var ev = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
    ev.initMouseEvent(
        'click',
        true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
        window, null,
        0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
        false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
        0 /*left*/, null
    );
    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The click was being circumvented by the site's javascript. Luckily PhantomJS has a sendEvent function that sends the event the same as a real user would:

```
var rect = page.evaluate(function() {
    return $('a.whatever')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
});
page.sendEvent('click', rect.left + rect.width / 2, rect.top + rect.height / 2);
```

Found above solution via [PhantomJS; click an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element/24026636#24026636)

Comment: It's better not to duplicate content. If the solution worked for you, then it's best to confirm the duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

PhantomJS has two context. Only the page context, accessed through `page.evaluate()`, has access to the DOM and can trigger synthetic events. Since your `click()` function uses `document`, it needs to be run in the page context.

`page.evaluate()` is sandboxed, which is why you can't simply use variables that are defined outside. You either need to define them in the page context or you need to pass them in in a complicated manner (because only primitive objects can be pass into and out of the page context and functions are not primitive objects).

```
page.open(url, function(status) {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        if (typeof window.click !== "function") {
            window.click = function(el){
                var ev = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
                ev.initMouseEvent(
                    'click',
                    true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
                    window, null,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
                    false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
                    0 /*left*/, null
                );
                el.dispatchEvent(ev);
            }
        }
        var obj = document.querySelectorAll('button')[0];
        click(obj);
    });
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

References:

- Documentation of [`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)
- Ways to "click" in PhantomJS: [Q: PhantomJS; click an element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15739263/1816580)

Comment: This is useful, and I no longer get the TypeError message, however it does not solve the issue, i.e. it does not result in a clicking of the button. I'm wondering if there is some sort of javascript click prevention going on with the page I'm trying to click, is that a thing?

Comment: @zoltar Clicking is always tricky in PhantomJS. Have you gone through the solutions in the question I linked? Particularly, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24026636/1816580) works almost always.

Comment: Thanks Artjom, that is the solution that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    page.evaluate(function () {
        document.getElementById("login").click();
    });
```

does work... Not what you mean?

Comment: What is the difference between .click() and click(obj) ?

Comment: I ment the js function click - not your custom function. You state "...I understand I need to create my own function to click an element...", which isn't true as i understand it.

Comment: `element.click()` doesn't always work.