# How to use casperjs to click a random link and navigate to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

I am trying to write a script that will do the following:

1. load a website and take a screenshot
2. select a random `<a>` tag from all `<a>` tags with the same class name
3. click the link
4. wait for the new page to load
5. capture the second screenshot

I'm stuck at selecting a random `<a>` element and clicking it. Can anyone help me out please? It's my first day with casperjs. Here's what i have so far:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
     verbose: true,
     logLevel: 'debug',
     userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22',
     pageSettings: {}
});
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1600, height: 950};


casper.start('http://www.myurl.com/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    this.capture('home.png');
});

casper.then(function() {
        this.echo("Second test");
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * document.querySelector(".showall").length);
        var clicker = document.querySelector('.showall').eq(random);
        this.mouseEvent('click', clicker);

        this.wait(5000, function() {
            this.capture('second.png');
       });

});

casper.run();
```

Comment: What if you replace the `random` index to a hard-coded one? Does your script run as intended?

Comment: Not really. I only got it to click a particular element:
`casper.then(function() {
 this.echo("Second test");
 this.mouseEvent('click', '.showall');
 this.wait(5000, function() {
 this.capture('second.png');
   });
});`

Comment: By reading the `mouseEvent` function for capser, it seems to be expecting a selector query (ie, `.showall`) and not a jQuery object which `.eq()` returns.

Comment: Does the code work as intended if your query selector for `mouseEvent` use's the `nth-child` pseudo-selector? (ie, `.showall:nth-child(insert_number_here)`)

Comment: It only works with nth-child(1), although i'm 100% sure that there are about 20 `<a class="showall">` tags on the page. If nth-child is greater than one i get `CasperError: Cannot dispatch click event on nonexistent selector: .showall:nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't manage to get Artjom's solution working. I think i'm using `querySelectorAll` in a wrong way (not sure why). I found a workaround.

```
function getElem() {
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('a.showall');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(arr, function(elem) {
        return elem.getAttribute('href');
    });
}

casper.then(function() {

        var elem_arr = this.evaluate(getElem);
        //this.echo(elem_arr);
        this.echo(elem_arr.length);

        for (var index = 0; index < elem_arr.length; index++) {
            this.echo(elem_arr[index]);
        }

        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * elem_arr.length);
        this.echo(random);

        var clicker = elem_arr[random];
        this.echo("Random link: " + clicker);

        casper.open(clicker).then(function() {
            this.echo('Got it! You navigated to a random link subpage.');
        });


});
```

The trick is to create an array of links from all `a.showall` elements and then select a random link and open it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the DOM functions outside of the page context. You have to use [`casper.evaluate`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) for that. Keep in mind that `evaluate` is sandboxed and you can only pass primitive objects to and from page context. DOM elements are not primitive objects, so you cannot pass them outside into the casper context. `document` means nothing outside of `evaluate`.

From the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> Note: The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.

You will have to click the link with DOM methods inside of the page context. If the simple `clicker.click()` doesn't work, you have to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948355/1816580) in the page context.

If the link is actually a link which immediately navigates to the page, you can removed `this.wait`. CasperJS can sense on its own if a page is navigated to, so you can just use another `casper.then` step.

By the way `eq` is jQuery syntax, but the result of `querySelector` is not a jQuery object, it is a DOM element. If you want to select a random element then you have to use `querySelectorAll` and then select one of them:

```
var clicker = document.querySelectorAll('.showall')[random];
```

instead.

Complete solution:

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.echo("Second test");
    this.evaluate(function() {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".showall");
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length);
        var clicker = elements[random];

        // either this type of click
        clicker.click();
        // or the following
        var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
        ev.initMouseEvent(
            "click", true, true, window, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            false, false, false, false, 0, null
        );
        clicker.dispatchEvent(ev);
    });
});
casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('second.png');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Artjom. However, i noticed that none of the code from within `this.evaluate(function()` gets executed at all. What can be causing this? I had this problem before when i was trying to use `evaluate` myself. Is it a configuration issue..? Doesn't seem like it, but i'm not entirely sure.

Comment: It is executed, but you don't necessarily see the results. You should register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events.

Comment: Indeed, registering page.error helped and displayed the following error: `Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'clicker.click')`.

Comment: I completely missed that `querySelector` should be `querySelectorAll`. I added a reason. Please accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: It still does not work, but i will find a solution myself. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Have you tried both types of clicking? The other thing that you can try, is to remove the `this.wait(5000,` with `this.then(`, because casper will sense that there is a navigation to another page and wait for you until it is loaded. Also, you don't have to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer now.