# PhantomJS executing JavaScript in a popup for data extraction

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs, screen-scraping

So I have a web page with some photos of people. When you click on a photo of the person the JavaScript is executed and produces a popup with some more detailed information such as a description etc.

The link for each photo is as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data="10019"  class="seeMore"></a>
```

First I want to start with the basics, of just extracting the description etc. from one single person. So I want to execute the JavaScript above to write the popup window, and when I'm on the popup window I can then extract the content of the `div's` on the popup.

I've looked at PhantomJS and I really don't know where to start. I've used Cheerio to get some simple information from the page, and I want to move on to executing the popup window through JS and then extracting data from that.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm a bit of a newbie to screen scraping in general.

Comment: [cheers](https://github.com/fallanic/cheers), is based on cheerio, and supports headless browser, well not yet.

Comment: seems based on CSS selectors from that git page?

Comment: I don't know I never used it, it's based on cheerio so it might be yeah. But it doesn't support executing javascript as of yet in a headless browser, see the Roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this analogous to how [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) [does](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/casper.js#L2532-L2547) [it](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/casper.js#L2353-L2358).

```
page.open(yourUrl, function(success){
    // mainPage is loaded, so every next page could be a popup
    page.onPageCreated = function onPageCreated(popupPage) {
        popupPage.onLoadFinished = function onLoadFinished() {
            popupPage.evaluate(function(){
                // do something in popup page context like extracting data
            });
        };
    };

    // click to trigger the popup
    page.evaluate(function(){
        document.querySelector("a.seeMore").click();
        // or something from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element
    });
});
```

Do not forget to overwrite/nullify `page.onPageCreated` before navigating away from the main page.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go to see if I can get something to work

Comment: Please see my edit. The click has to be done in page context.