# PhantomJS: open (via simulated user click) a popup and get source code of new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-crawler, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS to retrieve the source code of a website after some AJAX manipulations of the DOM. Then using jQuery, I'm simulating a click on a button element (which has it's link hidden in an obscure JavaScript script). This button's `onClick` effect is to open a new window.

**What I'd like to do is retrieve the source code of this new window.**

What I cannot do is use the `window.open("url")` method in JS because I cannot retrieve the url of the new window since it's obfuscated in a script.

Some workaround I've been looking at but haven't succeeded to implement:

1. Return the new window in any way with the `click()` function.
2. Switch the focus to the new window in JS.
3. Retrieve the url of the button's `onClick` whitout having to parse the JS script.

Here's what I've got at the moment:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();

page.open("http://www.example.com", function() {
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        var page = page.evaluate(function() {
            $("#myButton").click(function() {
                // ???
            });
        });
        phantom.exit();
    });
});
```

I'm open to other frameworks/technologies if there is a solution!

Comment: Have you seen http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-page-created.html? Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25854614

Comment: Thanks, it didn't quite work as I wanted because the popup doesn't seem to load, but I found a workaround: the url of the popup appears in the callback `onResourceRequested`, so I'll parse it and then open the new page.