# Click a link in Phantomjs

Tags: html, web, phantomjs

I need to click a link in phantomjs. I've looked it up many times, but none of the examples worked. I'm very new to phantomjs and javascript, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhantomJS; click an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element)

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail?