# How do I get a popup open with PhantomJS only knowing the popup id?

Tags: javascript, onclick, phantomjs

I am trying to use PhantomJS to open a popup that is normally called via a link and dump a picture of that popup. I have only found ways using id's but all of the links have the same id, same href value, and same title. The only difference between all of the links is a 3 letter code in the showpopup function that corresponds to the 3 letter link text.

How can this be done? Can I just fire the `ShowPopup('XXX')` function or will I need to figure out a way to actually click the link?

```
<a href="#" id="ShowInfoHref" title="ABC" onclick="ShowPopup('XXX');return false;">XXX</a>
```

This link will then open up the popup:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="XXX" style="width: auto; min-height: 25.7667px; height: auto;">...code...</div>
```

Which I assume I think I can just have phantomjs screen dump that div correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to simply call `ShowPopup('XXX')`:

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    ShowPopup('XXX');
});
setTimeout(function(){
    // do something with it
}, 1000);
```

You could also [click the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element) with a specific attribute CSS selector `a[onclick*="XXX"]`. The `[attribute*=value]` selector matches the element where the attribute contains the value anywhere.