# Simulate mouseover in jasmine unit test?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, phantomjs, mouseover

Apologies if this is covered elsewhere, struggled to find comprehensive result on search.

I've got a Javascript app that has audio descriptions on mouseover for certain elements. These are implemented using mouseover listeners like so (pseudo-code!)

```
  menuOption.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    audio.play("menuoption"); 
  });
```

In my test I've got something like:

```
  spyOn(audio, "play")

  menuOption.mouseover()

  expect(audio.play.calls.count()).toBe(1);
```

This mouseover doesn't seem to fire. I'm using jasmine and phantomjs. When I change mouseover to click it works ok so I'm inclined to think my tests are fine and its mouseover thats a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just as `element.click()` is non-standard, so is `element.mouseover()`. You can try to explicitly generate the event (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948355/1816580) by torazaburo):

```
function mouseover(el){
    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    ev.initMouseEvent(
        "mouseover",
        true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
        window, null,
        0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
        false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
        0 /*left*/, null
    );
    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
mouseover(menuOption);
```