# Click a certain link on frame-based site, using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, frames

I have an frame based site and i need to click link in the left frame(menu) for getting new content in mainframe. Is this possible to do in phantomjs? Whats the algorythm? Thank you.

```
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName('frame')[2];
var links = frame.contentDocument.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var l = 0; l < links.length; l++){

     if(links[l].href.indexOf("home") > -1)
     {
       alert(links[l].href);
       //links[l].click();   
     }
}
```

That stuff doesn't work =\

Comment: What is the issue? You don't know how to click with PhantomJS or you don't know how to find the button that you need to click?

Comment: Actually, both. No methods that i know to find links on page are working.  A piece of javascript code that i posted doesn't work. Thats a fail on the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [switch to a frame](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/switch-to-child-frame.html) first, before you can do something in it. To actually click an element [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element) has all the answers:

```
page.switchToChildFrame(0); // select frame by index or name
page.evaluate(function(){
    function click(el){
        // copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948355
        var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
        ev.initMouseEvent(
            "click",
            true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
            window, null,
            0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
            false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
            0 /*left*/, null
        );
        el.dispatchEvent(ev);
    }

    click(document.querySelector('a[href*="home"]'));
});
// switch back when you're done
page.switchToParentFrame();
```

As seen here. You don't need to iterate over the elements to click it. Use `querySelector` appropriately with an attribute CSS selector. `[attribute*=value]` selects all elements whose `attribute` somewhere contains `value`.

Comment: I'am very grateful for your the solutions. You advices are really work out. Thanks a lot, one more time!