# NodeJS + PhantomJS + phantomJS-node + JQuery + click a link is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I tried to use the phantomjs(v1.9.8) module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) for node.js The goal was just to display the current url and navigate by programatically clicking the Next link using JQuery. Im unsuccessful in clicking the Next link. I tried doing it the hard way via document to no avail.

Kindly point me to the right direction on how to do this.

Code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

function scrape(keyword) {

    phantom.create("", {}, function(ph) {

        console.log("Phantom Bridge Initiated");

        ph.createPage(function(page) {

            page.set("settings.javascriptEnabled", true, function() {
                console.log("...enabling javascript");
            });

            page.set("settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36", function() {
                console.log("...setting user agent");
            });         

            function traverse_page(page) {
                console.log('--- traverse_page ---');

                page.evaluate(function() {

                    console.log("HOW MANY NEXT IS FOUND : " + $(".paginationNext a").length);

                    if ($(".paginationNext a").length > 0) {
                        $(".paginationNext a")[0].click();  // doesnt work
                        // document.getElementsByClassName('paginationNext')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click() // doesnt work too
                    } 

                    return document;

                }, function(result) {

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        extract_values(page);
                    }, 10000);
                })
            }

            function extract_values(page) {
                console.log("--- extract values ---");

                page.evaluate(function() {
                    return {    "url": $(location).attr('href') };
                }, function(result) {
                    console.log("URL : " + result.url);
                    traverse_page(page);
                });
            }

            page.open("http://search.infospace.com/search/web?q=thylacine&searchbtn=Search", function(status) {

                page.set("onConsoleMessage",function(msg) {
                if(msg.indexOf("Unsafe JavaScript") == -1){
                    console.log(msg)}});

                page.includeJs("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js", function() {
                    extract_values(page);
                })
            });
        });
    });
}
scrape();
```

Result:

```
Phantom Bridge Initiated
...enabling javascript
...setting user agent
--- extract values ---
URL : http://search.infospace.com/search/web?q=thylacine&searchbtn=Search
--- traverse_page ---
phantom stdout: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(".paginationNext a")[0].click()')


phantom stdout:   phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():6
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():11
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():11

HOW MANY NEXT IS FOUND : 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duplicate of [PhantomJS; click an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element)

you may also want to read about http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html

Comment: tnx for pointing me to the right direction. the info on the first link worked. specifically, the solution that worked was in the dispatching of a click event using a MouseEvent.