# PhantomJS open one page after another

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I used this example to create a phantomjs code to login to website.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open("http://www.facebook.com/login.php", function(status) {

  if (status === "success") {
    page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
      console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
    };
    page.evaluate(function() {
      console.log('hello');
      document.getElementById("email").value = "email";
      document.getElementById("pass").value = "password";
      document.getElementById("u_0_1").click();
      // page is redirecting.
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      page.evaluate(function() {
        console.log('haha');
      });
      page.render("page.png");
      phantom.exit();
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

From this link.
https://gist.github.com/ecin/2473860

But I want to open another link from a button or go directly on it. How can I do it?

Here is a simpler example. Doesn't work...

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = "www.example.com";

page.open(url, function (status) {

    setTimeout(function () {
        page.evaluate(function () {
            console.log('haha');
        });
        page.render("example.png");
        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000);

});



var url = "www.google.com";

page.open(url, function (status) {

    setTimeout(function () {
        page.evaluate(function () {
            console.log('haha');
        });
        page.render("google.png");
        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000);

});
```

Comment: Note than PhantomJS has a different execution environment than node. There are bridges between node and PhantomJS, but they are written slightly different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very close, now combine your two snippets into one. `page.open()` is asynchronous which is why you need to open the next page only after the first one has finished:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = "http://www.example.com";

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};

page.open(url, function (status) {
    page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
        console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
    };
    page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById("email").value = "email";
        document.getElementById("pass").value = "password";
        document.getElementById("u_0_1").click();
        // page is redirecting.
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        page.evaluate(function () {
            console.log('haha');
        });
        page.render("example.png");


        var url = "http://www.google.com";

        page.open(url, function (status) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                page.evaluate(function () {
                    console.log('haha');
                });
                page.render("google.png");
                phantom.exit();
            }, 5000);
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

To actually see the `console.log()` inside of `page.evaluate()` you will need to register to the [`page.onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) event. There are more other events that are helpful when debugging.

Don't forget to add the protocol (http:// or file:///) to the URLs that you're opening. PhantomJS is a bit picky in that regard.

Instead of waiting a static amount of time (`setTimeout()`) until the next page is loaded after you do some action. You should make use of the `page.onLoadFinished` event. This is rather cumbersome to get right for navigation intensive scripts. Use [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) for longer scripts.

Oftentimes `Element.click()` doesn't work. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element) has many solutions for those cases.

Comment: Ok. This has worked but what if I want to enter something in google search box and press button to search. Then I get rendered search results?

Comment: @macroscripts Google is a really bad site to start experimenting with PhantomJS. But you would use `page.evaluate()` to change the value of an input field and [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element) the search button. You can also use `page.sendEvent()` to fill the field and hope that instant results are enabled for PhantomJS.

Comment: I am using google as an example. I am doing this code on website. It has different domains. I have to login from sub1.domain.com and get access to sub2.domain.com . I want to get some data from it.

The code you gave me works but not fully. It gets to sub1 but doesn't login properly. And it goes to sub2 but I don't see my username logged in. 

I'll paste the example I used later.

Comment: Make it a new question if you have a problem with that. Also, please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959899/phantomjs-login-after-another-login

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough where the second script must be inserted into the first one. You still have to wait a little after clicking. That should answer your linked question.

Comment: You mean this line document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Sign In']")[0].click();

So how do I insert the waiting time?

Comment: You already do that with the `setTimeout()` call in the first script. You only need to insert the second script into the `setTimeout()` callback. Please look at the answer diff.

Comment: I did use setTimeout in second script... twice

Comment: @ArtjomB. would you please take a look on my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171792/generate-har-file-from-array-of-links-using-phantomjs ? I really need some help to implement your solution... Thanks!

Comment: How would this solution change if, instead of calling another site (in this case www.google.com) as the second page, the same page is reloaded using `svgDocument.location.reload();`? Thank you.