# Interacting with QlikView using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, qlikview

I am trying to simulate traffic on QlikView dashboards for the purposes of load testing. I have created a number of simple dashboards that I am viewing in a web browser. When I click anywhere on a graph or select a field in a list box, I can see that network traffic is generated as the application filters to display updated results.

I would like to simulate this traffic by opening the dashboards with PhantomJS and pretending to click on a few different places. Ideally, I would like to select an object such as chart or listbox and click on that programmatically but clicking on random coordinates within the page should suffice as well. However, the usual JS/JQuery click() operations do not appear to have any effect within QlikView even when displayed in a browser.

Any input as to how to approach this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Some additional info per comment: Yes, unfortunately I've tried everything on that page and just about everything else produced by stackoverflow/google searches. I can grab elements and do all the normal operations but the pages produced by qlikview  are structured differently from any I've worked with. The majority of the elements are clickable and you actually interact with dashboards by dragging the mouse over sections of graphs to zoom in, or selecting criteria from listboxes. Somehow they fire Ajax calls from deep in qlikview's js but on the surface all elements appear as mostly divs and spans without explicit onclick functionality which may be why they don't respond to anything I've tried so far. For this reason I think moving further away from working with individual elements and simulating something like selecting a random portion of the screen may be best but no luck so far.

Comment: You mean you tried everything from [Q: PhantomJS; click an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element?s=0|6.1326)?

Comment: Hey Artjom, I added some info above regarding the comment.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help with the underlying problem you're having, but I was thinking maybe you could try setting up some bookmarks in your dashboards, then use PhantomJS  to toggle between the bookmarks (which should cause network traffic as the selections contained in the bookmark are activated) in the nav bar that Qlik adds by default at the top of all dashboards. Perhaps the `click()` element will work on the nav bar? Just a thought.