# Create alert in Google Alert using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, phantomjs, onclicklistener

If you go to [Google Alert](https://www.google.com/alerts) website while you are not login with your Google Account you would have a chance of creating an alert send to your Yahoo account for example.

I am going create an alert using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). Then I would need to click on the CREATE ALERT button. I need to do that using JavaScript. But it seems that PhantomJS cannot click on this button!

I have even tried to click on this button through Google Console but I could not.

I have used three different ways for clicking on the button which nothing works. Can someone help me to click on the CREATE ALERT button?

```
javascript:if(!window.jQuery||confirm('Overwrite\x20current\x20version?\x20v'+jQuery.fn.jquery))(function(d,s){s=d.createElement('script');s.src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.js';(d.head||d.documentElement).appendChild(s)})(document);

var inputOne = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
inputOne.value = "testAlert";

var inputTwo = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];
inputTwo.value = "test@yahoo.com";

var button = document.getElementById('create_alert');

//1.
//button.click();

//2.
//$(button).trigger('click');
//$(button).trigger('change');

//3.
var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
button.dispatchEvent(event);
```

And I am using following code in PhantomJS

```
phantom.injectJs("functions/jquery.js");

var page = require('webpage').create();

var load, contoroller;
var numOfActions = 1;
var clicked = false;

var initialURL = "https://www.google.com/alerts";

page.open(initialURL, function(status) {

    load = true;
});


page.onLoadFinished = function(status) 
{

    clearInterval(contoroller);
    if (clicked)
    {
        console.log("The status of loading the page is " + status + "\n");
        page.render("SCREENSHOTS/page_" + numOfActions + ".png");
        numOfActions += 1;

        phantom.exit();
    }
    else
    {
        contoroller = setInterval(function () {

            if (load)
            {
                console.log("The status of loading the page is " + status + "\n");
                page.render("SCREENSHOTS/page_" + numOfActions + ".png");
                numOfActions += 1;

                load = false;

                enterQuery("test");
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("The status of loading the page is " + status + "\n");
                page.render("SCREENSHOTS/page_" + numOfActions + ".png");
                numOfActions += 1;

                page.evaluate(function(){
                    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];
                    input.value = "test@test.com";

                })

                click();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}


function enterQuery(query)
{
    page.injectJs("functions/jquery.js");

    page.evaluate(function(query)
    {
        var box = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        box.value = query;
        //$(box).keypress();
    }, query);
}


function click()
{
    clicked = true;
    clearInterval(contoroller);

    var but = page.evaluate(function(){

        var button = document.getElementById('create_alert');

        //var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        //event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        //button.dispatchEvent(event);

        return button;

    })

    page.sendEvent('click', but);

    window.setTimeout(function () { 

        console.log("The status of loading the page is " + status + "\n");
        page.render("SCREENSHOTS/page_" + numOfActions + ".png");
        numOfActions += 1;

        phantom.exit();

    }, 5000);
}
```

It seems that I need to first hover the mouse on the button. When you hover the mouse you will see that the `class` attribute of the element changes. I have tried `$(button).trigger('mouseover')` but after that the `class` attribute did not change. How can I trigger `mouseover` on this element?

Comment: You say you tried 3 different methods. I see only one. Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24026636/1816580) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20022929/1816580)?

Comment: I just tried `page.sendEvent()` which you suggested. I have updated the `click()` function in my code. It did not work either. Have you tried it in Chrome? Don't you thinkd that I need to trigger the `mouseover` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code: typing and clicking.

When you set the value of an input field directly, none of the input event handlers are called. You could use the native [`page.sendEvent("keypress", keys)`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html) which types keys as if a user would type them, so all event handlers will be triggered. Since the function doesn't know where to type to, you need to focus on the element first:

```
page.evaluate(function(selector){
    document.querySelector(selector).focus();
}, selector);
page.sendEvent("keypress", query);
```

You can solve the clicking also with `page.sendEvent("click", posx, posy)`. Now the challenge becomes to find out the position of the elements on the page. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026636/1816580) provides a jQuery way of solving this:

```
page.injectJs("jquery.min.js");

var rect = page.evaluate(function(selector) {
    return $(selector)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
}, selector);

page.sendEvent('click', rect.left + rect.width / 2, rect.top + rect.height / 2);
```

---

This is your full script that works as expected:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

var load, contoroller;
var numOfActions = 1;
var clicked = false;

var initialURL = "https://www.google.com/alerts";

page.open(initialURL, function(status) {
    load = true;
});


page.onLoadFinished = function(status) 
{

    clearInterval(contoroller);
    if (clicked)
    {
        console.log("1| The status of loading the page is " + status + "\n");
        page.render("SCREENSHOT/page_" + numOfActions + ".png");
        numOfActions += 1;

        phantom.exit();
    }
    else
    {
        contoroller = setInterval(function () {

            if (load)
            {
                console.log("2| The status of loading the page is " + status + "\n");
                page.render("SCREENSHOT/page_" + numOfActions + ".png");
                numOfActions += 1;

                load = false;

                enter("input", "test"); // very first input
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("3| The status of loading the page is " + status + "\n");
                page.render("SCREENSHOT/page_" + numOfActions + ".png");
                numOfActions += 1;

                enter("input.email_input", "test@test.com");

                setTimeout(function(){
                    click("#create_alert");
                }, 500);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}


function enter(selector, query)
{
    page.evaluate(function(selector){
        document.querySelector(selector).focus();
    }, selector);
    page.sendEvent("keypress", query);
}


function click(selector)
{
    clicked = true;
    clearInterval(contoroller);

    page.injectJs("functions/jquery.js");

    var rect = page.evaluate(function(selector) {
        return $(selector)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    }, selector);

    page.sendEvent('click', rect.left + rect.width / 2, rect.top + rect.height / 2);

    window.setTimeout(function () { 

        console.log("4| The status of loading the page is " + status + "\n");
        page.render("SCREENSHOT/page_" + numOfActions + ".png");
        numOfActions += 1;

        phantom.exit();

    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it works flawless! You did a great help to me!