# CasperJS does not trigger AJAX upon a selector click

Tags: javascript, php, html, phantomjs, casperjs

My CasperJS project scrapes a web page that sends an AJAX request upon a button click. But when I triggered the button click, nothing seems to be happening. I had this problem of not triggering a DIV button but now I have a doubt whether it blocks any AJAX requests that are made from the remote page. (Here is my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697141/casperjs-cannot-click-on-a-div-button) on this.)

The remote page has a form to be filled and a DIV button to click which sends an AJAX request that shows the result. But in here I cannot see any click event is triggered nor ajax request is sent in the debug mode with verbose on. I have seen a similar question here but I have no access to change the access rights or proxy configurations in remote location.

How can I get this done?

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one other than having less information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CasperJS cannot click on a DIV button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697141/casperjs-cannot-click-on-a-div-button)

Comment: @ArtjomB. This is regarding AJAX. My previous problem was regarding a click on a DIV in which sends an AJAX request upon a click. I was trying few days to get that click working but failed. Now with this question I am assuming a failure in AJAX  if it wasn't a problem with the click.

Comment: Well, it is still basically the same question with a slightly different focus.