# How to click on a simple link?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, phantomjs

I've logged in on a Webpage using PhantomJS. Everything works fine. I printed the page and know that I am logged in. Now I want to click on a link, which is called "Analysis" and the following html code.

```
 <div class="navbar-subnav" data-id="Dashboard">
  <ul class="tab-list nav navbar-nav">

            <li class='active'><a href="/"><i class='icon-chart-pie'></i> Dashboard</a></li>

            <li><a href="/index/analyses"><i class='icon-search'></i> Analysis</a></li>

            <li><a href="/date_time/set_date_time"><i class='icon-cog'></i> Settings</a></li>

            <li><a href="/report/report" onclick="setTimeout(showLoading, 50);"><i class='icon-chart-area'></i> Reports</a></li>

            <li><a href="/manual/csc"><i class='icon-info-circled'></i> About</a></li>


</ul>
```

Usually I "click" on a element using

```
document.getElementById("logInButton").click();
```

but there is no ID in this case. 
So how can I navigate to /index/analysis when I'm currently in /index?

As I had to log in I have to use the same session so a simple `page.open` command didn't work.

I tried

```
 function(){

console.log(document.querySelector('[href="/index/analyses"]'));
    document.querySelector('[href="/index/analyses"]').click();
},
```

but it the log always shows

```
null
'TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector('[href="/index/analyses"]').click')

ama.js:52
ama.js:76 in executeRequestsStepByStep
```

and spams the log with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhantomJS; click an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element)

Comment: You said that the element exists, but then the error wouldn't be there. Please show a complete and minimal example of your PhantomJS script. [Guessing](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) is not the right way to go about solving this.

Comment: acutally it does exist as you can see in the source code. but know it works. i answered on this thread. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it with a simple

```
function(){         
        page.open('https://localhost/index/analyses',function(status){
    });    
},
```

Comment: He is trying to do this dinamically. What if the links generates some parameter like ?parameterA=hello, then this will not work!

Answer (score 1):

You could get the element thanks to its `href` attribute value:

`document.querySelector('[href*="/index/analyses"]')`

Then you can trigger a click event or anything you want with it :)

querySelector is supported since IE8 ([*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)).

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/e5new5sp/1)

Comment: function(){
        console.log('Clicking link');
        document.querySelector('[href="/index/analyses"]').click(); 
    }     gives me the error 

TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector('[href="/index/analyses"]').click')

  ama.js:51
  ama.js:75 in executeRequestsStepByStep

Comment: @Helyx At this point you might want to debug and `console.log()` different values (like the content of the querySelector function, to ensure it gets the element correctly).

Comment: Hmm it doest get the correct value indeed. console.log(document.querySelector('[href="/index/analyses"]'));   always returns null. Just checked the link again and it seems to be correct

Comment: @Helyx Have you verified that the element exists on the page with either a screenshot or by printing the page source? If it's not there, have you tried waiting for it?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes, i added some more html code to my orginal post

Comment: @ArtjomB. You are right, it might be a more appropriate query in this case. Updated the answer. Helyx, are the elements added to the page dynamically? The script might be running before the element is actually within the page.

Answer (score 1):

If on your page there is only one `<li>` element with class '`active`' then you can write:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].children[0].click();
```

If you have more `<li class="active">` elements inside some `<ul id="elementID">` element then you can write something like:

```
var ul = document.getElementsById('elementID');
var li = ul.children[0];//Here 0 is index of the first child, but if you want second element you can put 1 etc.
var a = li.children[0];//Here is your <a> element 
a.click();
```

### Update

This should work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tab-list")[0].children[1].children[0].click()
```

Comment: what would the elementID be in my case? (see source code above) the href?

Comment: See update. Update will work if this <ul class="tab-list nav navbar-nav"> is the first element in the document with this class. Try, and if it is not, copy and paste the whole content of the HTML document.

Comment: Also, if there is Jquery available on the website (and I assume it is), you can use jquery in Phantom evaluate function, which is 100 times easier.

Comment: now i'm getting TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByClassName("tab-list")[0].children')       I've never worked with Jquery, so for me it is not easy.

Comment: Just copy and paste the whole html document here pls.