# Phantomjs: Get element without id

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, href

html:

```
...
<a href="#" class="stuff">stuff</a>
...
<a id="yui_random_numbers" href="#" class="stuff">stuff</a>
```

2nd line is from outerHTML/source which page.content doesnt provide

As far as I am aware these 'buttons' have to be clicked with a custom mouse event, but since this one doesn't have an ID I am unsure how to get the element in the first place.

code:

```
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0'
page.open(address, function(status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            click(document.getElementById('wtf is dat id doe?'))
        })
    }
})
```

click function looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element) one in the answer.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.querySelector` should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementById` is not the only DOM selector available. You should read more about this on the MDN site like the [`querySelector` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDocument.querySelector).

When you will have the correct element selected, you call your `click` function like you do with the `getElementById`.

Comment: thanks a bunch, new to this had no idea really what to google.