# PhantomJS: Can't submit input by clicking or submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I have this element

```
<div class="btn">
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="submit(user)" value="Sign In" />
</div>
```

that submits login data. I tried following ways, but they not working:

```
$('div[class="btn"] > input').click();
$('div[class="btn"] > input').submit();
```

How to submit by other way?

Comment: I'm using version 2.0 without Casper.

Comment: Sorry, used the wrong template. Here is the correct one: Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Are you sure that the page has fully loaded and the elements are there? Have you taken a screenshot to see if they are?

Comment: Yes, login form is visible on a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's events are maintained in local scope, and using an injected jQuery to `click` from PhantomJS will not necessarily invoke the event you want--you'd have to obtain a handle to the **page** jQuery.

However, you're probably trying to test user behavior. A better test is to dispatch a click as a user event, as described here: [PhantomJS; click an element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15739263/603369)