# Click on all 'a' elements in paragraph with specific class in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, click, casperjs

I have the following problem.
I have this structure of HTML code:

```html
<p class="description">
    lorem ipsum, bla bla bla 
    <a href="# onclick="somemethod(id)">click</a>
</p>
<p class="description">
    lorem ipsum, bla bla bla
</p>
<p class="description">
    lorem ipsum, bla bla bla 
    <a href="# onclick="somemethod(id)">click</a>
</p>
```

Now I need to click via CasperJS on every "a" in paragraphs with class 'description'.

I try this:

```js
while (selector = document.querySelector('p.description a')) {
    casper.then(function () {
        this.click(selector);
        console.log('click');
    })
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Are there any possibilities how to do this?

Comment: Does it actually make sense to click *all* those paragraphs without reloading the page?

Comment: Yes, because each of this links calls javascript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

- You cannot use `document` and `casper` at the same time, because `document` is only available inside of the page context (`casper.evaluate()`), but `casper` is not available in the page context.
- You need to iterate over the clickable elements either fully in the page context or fully outside.

---

#### CSS selectors

If all `<p>` elements have the same parent and there are no other elements in between, then you can simply use CSS selectors to achieve this:

```
casper.then(function(){
    var numberOfElements = this.getElementsInfo("p.description").length;
    for(var i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++) {
        this.click("p:nth-child("+i+") a");
    }
});
```

Note that it's not possible to select `:nth-child` based on the class, so this also assumes that no `<p>` elements are there without the "description" class.

#### XPath expressions

It's possible to make this much more robust, by using XPath expressions, because they are much more expressive.

```
var x = require("casper").selectXPath;
...
casper.then(function(){
    var numberOfElements = this.getElementsInfo("p.description").length;
    for(var i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++) {
        this.click(x("(//p[contains(@class,'description')])["+i+"])/a"));
    }
});
```

where `(//p[contains(@class,'description')])["+i+"])` means that a NodeList (`//p[contains(@class,'description')]`) of p elements is built which all contain "description" as part of their "class" attribute. Then e.g. `(nodeList)[3])` selects the third element from that list.

---

If you want to iterate inside of the page context, then you need to use [a click function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948355/1816580) inside of the page context.