# CasperJS/PhantomJS Get nodes and click them

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to get DOMElements and click on each of them. After that I want to run assertions on the response.

```
var nodes = this.evaluate(function(){
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.editable .action');
    return nodes;
});

//Print the base URI for the node
for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
    if(null != nodes[i]){
        require('utils').dump(nodes[i].baseURI);
    }
}
```

I have around 5 nodes that are a match, but nodes[0] is the only one that is not null. The rest are null in CasperJS. However running the same test in chrome browser I get all the nodes, none of them are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CasperJS is built upon PhantomJS and has the same limitations. One of those limitations is that there are two contexts and the page context which has access to the DOM is sandboxed. It's not possible to pass non-primitive objects such as DOM nodes out of the page context.

[Documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

You cannot compare this with Chrome, because Chrome doesn't have two contexts in normal operation.

You can pass **representations** of DOM nodes out of the page context. CasperJS has some convenience functions for this like [`casper.getElementsInfo(selector)`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo).

If you want to **click** every element, then there are different ways to achieve that depending on how the elements are positioned on the page. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33465151/1816580) shows two ways with CSS selectors and XPath expressions outside of the page context.

See also:

- [`casper.evaluate(fn, args...)`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. I will look through the information you provided.