# PhantomJs Click Element Inside Frame

Tags: phantomjs

I have a page with two frames:

```
<frameset>
<frame src="left.php" name="left">
<frame src="right.php" name="right">
<span id="aButton"><a href="gosomewhere.php"><span class="buttonContainer"><span class="buttonText">a button</span></span></a></span>
</frameset>
```

I want to click the link inside the second frame like this:

```
page.render("screen1.jpg");
page.switchToFrame("right");
var recta = page.evaluate(function() {
  return document.querySelector('#aButton a').getBoundingClientRect();
});

page.sendEvent('click', recta.left + recta.width / 2, recta.top + recta.height / 2);
page.render("screen2.jpg");
console.log(page.frameContent);
```

However, the click does not seem to register as my `screen2.jpg` shows no change. `frameContent` only shows html from frame "`right`", so I know that `switchToFrame` is working.

Is there a special way to handle clicking inside frames beyond the `switchToFrame` function? I have also tried `document.querySelector('#aButton a').click()` but no luck.

Comment: Does the click trigger some kind of request? If so, then you need to wait for it's response.

Comment: It just loads a new page inside the frame. I'm using a typical waitFor, but that isn't the problem. Even inside the waitFor I have screenshots that all look the same as screen1.jpg, so it seems clear the link isn't getting clicked.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. Have you tried other solutions from here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15739263/1816580