# CasperJS click() in evaluate immediately returns null, ignores other lines

Tags: javascript, click, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to write an evaluate function in CasperJS, but I'm running into an issue when I call a click event. Here's a quick code block to illustrate the problem:

```
returnVal = casper.evaluate(() ->
    document.querySelector('.class').click()
    return true
```

`returnVal` is always null in the above, even when the class exists.

In my actual code I have a good deal of code to run, and I want to do multiple click events throughout.

Is it the design of CasperJS to immediately return when a `click()` is called? Or am I missing something really simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register to some error event like "page.error":

```
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Error: " + msg);
});
```

then you will see that `click()` is not a function that can be called. PhantomJS 1.x only supports `click()` on `<input>` and `<button>` elements and even that is not consistent. Use CasperJS' own click function if you want consistent behavior:

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.click(".class");
});
```

The result of the `evaluate()` call is always null (`undefined`), because the `return` statement is never executed. An uncaught error is thrown in the line before that.

This is written in JavaScript, but applies in exactly the same way to CoffeeScript.

Comment: Thanks. Is there absolutely no way to do a normal JavaScript click event in a evaluate function? The website I'm dealing with uses a virtual DOM, so `this.click(".class")` unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: You can add a custom synthetic click function inside of the page context in [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15948355/1816580), but I doubt this will work better. I guess you need to figure out what the real DOM nodes behind the virtual nodes are.