# Phantomjs doesn't click on a tag <a>

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, server-side

I tried many times to click on a `<a>` tag, but phantomjs doesn't see it, even if I see it when I render the page.

I tried to use this trick, it won't work.

```
var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');

evObj.initEvent('click', true, false);

document.getElementById('TEST').dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhantomJS; click an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element)

Comment: I think they are now called MouseEvent. ex: `var newEvent = new MouseEvent("click")`

Comment: It doesn't work either..  :'(  I also tried to click on a specific point giving x and y coordinates on the document.. no results..

Comment: @FedericoGiorgioSalani Please show your full code ([edit] your question). I suspect that you're not running this in the page context. Additionally, it's not clear how you're verifying that some has happened.