# PhantomJS not clicking button

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, salesforce

For some reason the javascript I execute with PhantomJS does not click the save button it does however execute in Firefox console without issue.

It dosent give me any errors either.

Javascript in question

```
var enableCheckbox = document.querySelector('input[id*="togglePref"]');
if(!enableCheckbox.hasAttribute('checked')){
    enableCheckbox.click();
    console.log(document.querySelector('input[value="Save"]').value);
}
```

PhantomJS Script

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var url = page.url;
    var domainUrl = url.substr(0, url.length - 13);
    console.log(domainUrl);

    page.render('logedIn.png');

    page.open(domainUrl + 'setup/notesSetupPage.apexp?setupid=NotesSetupPage');
    do { phantom.page.sendEvent('mousemove'); } while (page.loading);
    setTimeout(function(){
            page.evaluate(function(){
                var enableCheckbox = document.querySelector('input[id*="togglePref"]');
                if(!enableCheckbox.hasAttribute('checked')){
                    enableCheckbox.click();
                    console.log(document.querySelector('input[value="Save"]').value);
                }
            });
        page.render('diditsave.png');
        console.log('...finished');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000);
}, 5000);
```

If anyone has any ideas why this might be the case I would greatly appreciate the help.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Why not `if(!enableCheckbox.checked){` ?

Comment: Have you tried the other ways to click? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15739263/1816580

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavascriptExecutor: http://selenium-solutions.blogspot.in/2012/11/enabling-hidden-element-using.html