# vue karma, how to write unit test

Tags: karma-runner, vue.js

Is there any example how to write test case in `vue`? The **click** event not working.

**The template in App.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="main">
<textarea v-model="input" id="input" rows="3" placeholder="Please entry colors, eg: '#000','#fff' or ['#000', '#fff']"></textarea>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary parse" @click="parse">Go!</button>
<ul>
    <li v-for="color in colors">
      <span v-bind:style="{ background: color}"></span>
      {{color}}
    <li>
</ul>
```

**karma test**

```
describe('App.vue', () => {
it('should render correct color', () => {
const vm = new Vue({
  template: "<div><app></app></div>",
  components: {
    App
  }
}).$mount()
console.log(vm.$el)
vm.input = '#333, #444'
vm.$el.querySelector('.btn').click()
expect(vm.$el.querySelector('ul li:eq(0) span').style.background).toBe('#333')
 })
})
```

And I have output the `vm.$el`, it shows like below, missing the `v-model` and `@click`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does it give you any error? Are you using PhantomJS as browser?
I don't think click is supported on PhantomJS
See here [PhantomJS; click an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element)

Comment: See the 'see here' in my answer for how to trigger click