# Phantomjs click on checkbox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, click, phantomjs

I'm using selenium and phantomjs and I would like to learn how to click a checkbox properly. For exemple in this page: https://www.udacity.com/courses/android

I would like to check "Free Courses", so I tried this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="checkbox"]/label[contains(.,"Free Courses")]')
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

The problem is that it doesn't seems to be clicking anything: making a screenshot with `self.driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')` it gives all the results, not filtered.
Is it something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why not to use `self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="checkbox"]/label[contains(.,"Free Courses")]').click()` ? Also you should use `input` element instead of `label`

Comment: The .click() function seems to be not supported in PhantomJS, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element
It's true I was using label erroneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xpath` locates to `label` element while you want to click on `checkbox` element, As I'm seeing in your provided [website](https://www.udacity.com/courses/android), there is no need to create `xpath` to select `Free Course` checkbox, you can simply find this checkbox using `By.NAME` as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')

   def parse(self, response):
      self.driver.get(response.url)
      element = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Free Course')
      element.click()
```

**Note** :- Selenium provides `click()` function to perform click on an element, So there is no need to use `execute_script` to perform click by javascript if you could simply do this by using `click()` function.

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Thanks, it works! I used the execute_script 'cause I read that in PhantomJS the click() function doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: @LaraM. You welcome, Glad to help you..due some reasone like designing or other issues `click()` does not work then you can use `execute_script` otherwise `click()` works perfectly....:)