# Cron job to download a file that is the response of a form submit

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I need to implement a cron job on my nodejs backend that does the following tasks:

1. Go to a specific url
2. Click on a button to download a ZIP-File. This download is the response of a form submit (POST).
3. Store the file somewhere on the server.

I know how to implement cron jobs. My problem is that download. Unfortunately there is no direct download link... So as far as I understand the only way around this is to "simulate" the click on the form button somehow... Maybe using a headless browser?

Has anyone ever done this before? I'd be glad about some inputs.

Cheers
Michael

Comment: are you able to make the same post request the form makes to the same script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element might be helpful