# PhantomJS; click an element using Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to automate test cases headless with selenium using Java. As described in [PhantomJS; click an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element/43893798#43893798) , simply clicking is not possible with PhantomJS. Instead of clicking the element a NullPointerException is thrown.

Unfortunately, the answers I found only explain solutions in Javascript.

Has anybody found a solution for Java?

Thanks and best regards

AcMuDD

Comment: you ncan use a custom waitAndClick() method which waits for element to be visible, clickable and then use Actions class to focus the element and click it

Comment: If your problem is the same as shown in the link, then are you also trying to click a span instead of a clickable element?  Please provide a section of the html code and what you've attempted along with result.

Comment: Hi kushal, hi Bill,Sorry for answering late. At the moment I have another problem with my code. I'll still need a little time and give you detailed information after solving this. @kushal: I tried with waiting 50 seconds. It didn't help. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @AcMuD : did you use actions class' moveToelement() function

Comment: Yes I did. But I also tried driver.findElementBy.xpath(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For understanding working with PhantomJS better I tried it for an simple Google search today. These are the steps:

1. open Google (working)
2. make a screenshot (for validating the page has been load) (working)
3. Send keys "Hello" (not working)

This is my code:

```
    System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "webdriver/phantomjs.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

    driver.get("http://google.com");
    Thread.sleep(20000);        
    File file = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileCopyUtils.copy(file, new File("C:/Users/username/Desktop/screenshot.jpg")); 

    Actions a = new Actions(driver);

    a.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]"))).click().perform();
    a.sendKeys("Hello").perform();
```

I'm trying to click the textfield and type in "Hello". But I only get the error (sorry, I got a "NoSuchElementException", not a "NullPointerException")

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath
>   '//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]'","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"47","Content-Type":"application/json;
>   charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:39266","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_66)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"xpath\",\"value\":\"//*[@id=\\"lst-ib\\"]\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/1fae7fb0-3651-11e7-a707-9fe5bd25a173/element"}}
>   Command duration or timeout: 303 milliseconds For documentation on
>   this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.htmorg.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
>     at
>   testExamples.SeleniumPhantomJSHeadlessTest.init(SeleniumPhantomJSHeadlessTest.java:233)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:170)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:104)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
>
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has
>   been taken Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time:
>   '2016-03-15 16:57:40' System info: host: '', ip:
>   '', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version:
>   '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66' Driver info: driver.version:
>   RemoteWebDriver   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:138)
>     ... 30 more
>
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath
>   '//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]'","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"47","Content-Type":"application/json;
>   charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:39266","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_66)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"xpath\",\"value\":\"//*[@id=\\"lst-ib\\"]\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/1fae7fb0-3651-11e7-a707-9fe5bd25a173/element"}}
>   For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Update 12.05.2017: I found a solution there: http://it-kosmopolit.de/blog/2014/02/25/quick-start-of-running-selenium-webdriver-against-phantomjs-in-java-on-windows-plain-java/

Looking after WebElement using findElementBy.name("q") worked for me.