# PhantomJS: Cannot get Element

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have a PhantomJS script based on this one: http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-login-amazon-using-phantomjs-working-example/

It works very well, I can, for example, populate the login page and click on the "submit" button with code that looks like this:

```
function(){
    console.log('Step 3');
    page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById("username-pulldown").value="username";
        document.getElementById("password-pulldown").value="password";
        document.getElementById("login-pulldown"   ).click();
    });
},
```

Later-on, however, I try to execute this:

```
function(){
    console.log('Step 7');
    page.evaluate(function(){
        document.getElementById("content_text").value += "SomeTextIWannaAdd";
        //console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
        document.getElementByName("button");
    });
},
```

I get this error message:

```
Step 7
ERROR: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating
'document.getElementByName("button")')
TRACE:
 -> undefined: 3
 -> : 8

  phantomjs://code/EditWiki.js:48 in onError
```

The html element i want to get looks as follows:

```
<button name="button" type="submit" class="button -highlight -with-icon icon-checkmark">Save</button>
```

The rest of the innerHTML: https://pastebin.com/j5cCDxEU

Comment: I've already tried suggestions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element
It produces the exact same error. If I `return document.getElementByName("button");` and console.log it, I get `null`.

Comment: My god, now it works! Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document` object doesn't have a `getElementByName` method, only has `getElementsByName` method (plural).

Use `querySelector` instead to query by attribute name:

```
document.querySelector('[name="button"]')
```

To query all `button` tags you can use `getElementsByTagName`:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')
```

To query all buttons with a class name use `getElementsByClassName`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.button')
```

To emit a click event you can do:

```
document.querySelector('[name="button"]').click()
```

If using selectors that return an array such as `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementsByClassName` then you can grab the first one and then click:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.button')[0].click()
```

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to click on the element? I can select it now like this: `var e = document.getElementsByClassName("button -highlight -with-icon icon-checkmark");`
. When I click on it I get this error: `ERROR: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'e.click()')`

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me a lot of work. For the record, `document.querySelector('[name="button"]').click()` worked, while `document.getElementsByClassName('.button')[0].click()` returned an error: `ERROR: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByClassName('.button')[0].click')`

Answer (score 0):

Getting element by name is much error prone as there may be multiple 'buttons' try selecting the element by either xpath or id/class name.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked! `document.getElementsByClassName("button -highlight -with-icon icon-checkmark")`
And I thought I had tried all of these options!