# Custom function in phantomjs gives ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to learn phantomjs for automatically getting data from a site that's now protected with javascript.

I need to click on a link; as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536752/phantomjs-click-a-link-on-a-page) I tried to add the custom function "eventFire" to my phantomjs file, [as per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/simulate-click-javascript/2706236#2706236).  But no matter what I've tried it outputs `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: eventFire`

Could someone please tell me the proper way to do this? because I'm not seeing it, thank you.

I tried copying the function exactly and that didn't work, so I tried this also with the same result:

```
eventFire = function(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were using `page.evaluate`, you can pass the function as an argument.

```
page.evaluate(function(eventFire_fn) {
    // click your 'element'
    eventFire_fn(element, 'click');
}, eventFire);
```