# Click a href button with selenium (PhantomJS) and python

Tags: python, selenium, redirect, button, click

So i got this html from a website:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" dir="rtl" lang="he" id="vbulletin_html">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta id="e_vb_meta_bburl" name="vb_meta_bburl" content="http://www.fxp.co.il" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
<base href="//www.fxp.co.il" /><!--[if IE]></base><![endif]-->
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.fxp.co.il/login.php?do=login" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//images.fxp.co.il/images3/fav.png">
<meta name="generator" content="vBulletin 4.2.2" />
<meta name="keywords" content="FXP,פורום,פורומים,fxp,משחקים,סרטים,כיף,רשת,מחשבים,הורדות,הורדה,סרגל כלים,בדיקת IP,העלאת תמונות" />
<meta name="description" content="מחפשים אתר פורומים ?  אתר FXP מכיל קהילות פורומים, משחקים, תמונות גולשים ועוד. הכנסו עכשיו אל קהילות הפורומים של FXP" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="415294715208536" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="FXP" />
<meta property="og:description" content="מחפשים אתר פורומים ?  אתר FXP מכיל קהילות פורומים, משחקים, תמונות גולשים ועוד. הכנסו עכשיו אל קהילות הפורומים של FXP" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.fxp.co.il" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//images.fxp.co.il/css_static_main/main_fxp_20.2.14.css?v=7.11" />
<link href="//www.fxp.co.il/clientscript/awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//images.fxp.co.il/clientscript/yui-2.9.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var SESSIONURL = "";
var SECURITYTOKEN = "1456672267-7067c7f37055c9dd77a4fa83ba3b7b6f316c82b1";
var IMGDIR_MISC = "//images.fxp.co.il/images_new/misc";
var IMGDIR_BUTTON = "//images.fxp.co.il/images_new/buttons";
var vb_disable_ajax = parseInt("0", 10);
var SIMPLEVERSION = "4116";
var BBURL = "http://www.fxp.co.il";
var LOGGEDIN = 1152224 > 0 ? true : false;
var THIS_SCRIPT = "login";
var RELPATH = "login.php?do=login";
var PATHS = {
forum : "",
cms   : "",
blog  : ""
};
var AJAXBASEURL = "http://www.fxp.co.il/";

//var AJAXBASEURL = "//www.fxp.co.il/";

// -->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//images.fxp.co.il/clientscript/vbulletin-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//images.fxp.co.il/css_static_main/jquery.cookie_new.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ajax").load('notifc.php?userid=1152224');
$("#noti").click(function () {   
$("#ajax").load('notifc.php?userid=1152224');
}); 
$("#ajax_likes").load('likesno.php?userid=1152224');
$("#noti_like").click(function () {   
$("#ajax_likes").load('likesno.php?userid=1152224');
}); 
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//images.fxp.co.il/clientscript/set.js?v=6.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//images.fxp.co.il/clientscript/lazyload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
if (getCookie_bar('bbc_lazyload_fxp') != '1') {
$(".postbody img").lazyload({placeholder : "clear.gif", effect: "fadeIn"});
}
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//images.fxp.co.il/advertising/ads.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//images.fxp.co.il/skinfxp/s.php"></script>
<title>FXP</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var forumname = "";
var fxpcategory = "none";
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>DY = {scsec : 8765235 ,API: function(){(DY.API.actions = DY.API.actions || []).push(arguments)}};</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//dy2.ynet.co.il/scripts/8765235/api_static.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//dy2.ynet.co.il/scripts/8765235/api_dynamic.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-598971-1', 'auto');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');   
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Registered');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="standard_error">
<form class="block vbform" method="post" action="http://www.fxp.co.il/" name="postvarform">
<h2 class="blockhead">מעביר...</h2>
<div class="blockbody formcontrols">
<p class="blockrow restore">התחברת בהצלחה, Copy_Pasta.</p>
</div>
<div class="blockfoot actionbuttons redirect_button">
<div class="group" id="redirect_button">
<a href="http://www.fxp.co.il/" class="textcontrol">לחץ כאן אם הדפדפן אינו מעביר אותך אוטומטית</a>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2; URL=http://www.fxp.co.il/" />
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function exec_refresh()
{
 window.status = "מעביר..." + myvar;
 myvar = myvar + " .";
 var timerID = setTimeout("exec_refresh();", 100);
 if (timeout > 0)
 {
  timeout -= 1;
 }
 else
 {
  clearTimeout(timerID);
  window.status = "";
  window.location = "http://www.fxp.co.il/";
 }
}

var myvar = "";
var timeout = 20;
exec_refresh();
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The page above is supposed to redirect you to another page.
I'm looking to click on the button that redirects you immediately if you press it.

[It's this button if anyone's wondering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj3Qe.png)

This is the relevant code :

```
def login_and_redirect():
   #login into the site
   usrnm=raw_input("Please enter your username: ")
   pswrd=raw_input("Please enter your password: ")
   print("Logging in, please stand by...")
   driver.find_element_by_id("navbar_username").send_keys(usrnm)
   driver.find_element_by_id("navbar_password_hint").click()
   driver.find_element_by_id("navbar_password").send_keys(pswrd)
   driver.find_element_by_id("navbar_password").submit()
   #redirect to another page in the site after logging in
   driver.get("http://www.fxp.co.il/forumdisplay.php?f=236")
```

for some weird reason the function is stuck and phantomJS isn't beign redirected to the URL I wanted it to. My guess is it's because of the redirection page, so i'm trying to get around it by clicking the button. i'd appreciate any help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below xpaths to click on that re-direct button

```
 //div[@id='redirect_button']/a

  or

 //a[@href='http://www.fxp.co.il/']
```

Of-course you can also use css selector here..

Thanks,
Murali

Comment: I already tried that, I think it's something PhantomJS related because my code works just fine on firefox.

Comment: this will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536752/phantomjs-click-a-link-on-a-page

Comment: It's javascript though, i am using python.

Comment: in java i will use javascript executor to execute javascript to click on element.. so may try similar in puthon

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python

Comment: Ok i'll check it out!