# Is it possible access a CSS button via CURL/WGET?

Tags: php, css, curl, wget

I am trying to click on a CSS button via CURL/WGET, however so far I am having no luck. The exact link location for the CSS button is a dynamic URI - for example:

domain.com/some/page?thing=1

Still when you access that page via curl/wget it does not trigger the action. There is a CSS selector which I need to access somehow. I found this:

http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser

However it requires installing additional software which is not an option. I need something that would work with curl/wget or perhaps a sample PHP script. I tried providing the following argument to wget:

--header="selector: some-selector"

However it does not achieve the desired result.

Here is some more information from the comment, so that it is easier to see:

I've got the HTTP headers and tried to replicate them but with no luck. They are too long so I uploaded example headers to:

http://textuploader.com/oopa

Could anyone provide example script/command that could be used to achieve the above?

The action is not triggered by accessing the url - it requires you to click on a button. I have provided HTTP headers in my previous command. Here is what the exact button looks like when inspected:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:15px;">

  <a style="display:block; width:350px" href="http://www.test.com/hos/6/42?game=1" id="game-one">
    <img src="http://www.test.com/images/thumbs_up.jpg" width="24" height="24" />
                           Sample Text
  </a>

</div>
```

So basically I need to activate the game-one selector some how - simulate a click on that button via a script. The PHPBrowser that I mentioned above seems to offer this functionality, however I cannot install it as it requires additional software which is not an option in this case.

Comment: there's no "buttons" in http. there's just urls. curl would have to end up replicating exactly whatever request(s) the original html/js code are doing.

Comment: I've got the HTTP headers and tried to replicate them but with no luck. They are too long so I uploaded example headers to:

http://textuploader.com/oopa

Could anyone provide example script/command that could be used to achieve the above? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `click on a CSS button via CURL/WGET`? Any thing to do with CSS here? I don't think so.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "CSS button"? Can you provide a link to the page with the button?

Comment: As others have said you will need to use curl or wget to "post" the button url... You're basically faking a form submit or action but you can only use the relevant url to complete the action.

Comment: The action is not triggered by accessing the url - it requires you to click on a button. I have provided HTTP headers in my previous command. Here is what the exact button looks like:

<a id="game-one" href="http://www.test.com/hos/6/42?game=1" style="display:block; width:350px">

So basically I need to activate the game-one selector some how - simulate a click on that button via a script. The PHPBrowser that I mentioned in my original reply seems to offer this functionality, however I cannot install it as it requires additional software which is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone.

I was actually able to figure this out - it is possible via CURL. It appears that it was necessary to add referer set for the previous page, so in order to access the dynamic URI and trigger the action I used the following CURL:

```
curl --head --referer 'http://www.test.com/hos/6/42' http://www.test.com/hos/6/42?game=1
```

Answer (score 1):

In a comment below your question, you gave the following HTML for the "CSS button."

```
<a id="game-one" href="test.com/hos/6/42?game=1"; style="display:block; width:350px">
```

It's difficult to tell from this anchor alone, but it appears that you have a plain ol' link. In other words, to click this button is to click a link, which is to make an HTTP GET request to `test.com/hos/6/42?game=1` and render a page. If this is the case, then using curl or wget to request `test.com/hos/6/42?game=1` is effectively mimicking that button click (assuming cookies don't matter).

It's also possible that there is some Javascript code waiting to receive a click event from `id="game-one"`, but I can't tell for sure without looking at the page with the "CSS button." But if that's the case, consider triggering a click event using Javascript. See [How to simulate a click with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript/2706236#2706236) for a plain Javascript implementation or [Simulating Button click in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569320/simulating-button-click-in-javascript/14569348#14569348) for a JQuery implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately accessing the link does not get the job done - not via web browser, and not via CURL either - it simply accesses the web page on which the button is located, however it does not trigger the button's action.. I cannot provide the exact page, as it is currently in test period and it is not publicly accessible - that is why I am providing only sample information, sill I think that the information should be sufficient if the above is possible... I will update my original reply with more information regarding the button.

Comment: When you say "button's action," are you saying that there is some Javascript code executing in response to a click event?