# Click Event Not Firing After Drag (sometimes) in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

### Observed Behavior

I'm using d3.js, and I'm in a situation where I'd like to update some data based on a [`drag`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#wiki-on) event, and redraw everything after the [`dragend`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#wiki-on) event.  The draggable items also have some `click` behavior.

Draggable items can only move along the x-axis.  When an item is dragged, and the cursor is directly above the draggable item on `dragend/mouseup`, the item must be clicked twice after it is re-drawn for the `click` event to fire.  When an item is dragged, but `dragend/mouseup` does not occur directly above the item, the `click` event fires as expected (on the first try) after the redraw.

### Desired Behavior

I'd like the `click` event to always fire on the first click after dragging, regardless of where the cursor is.

If I replace the `click` event on the draggable items with a `mouseup` event, everything works as expected, but `click` is the event I'd really like to handle.

### A Demonstration

Here is a self-contained example: http://jsfiddle.net/RRCyq/2/

And here is the relevant javascript code:

```
var data, click_count,did_drag;
// this is the data I'd like to render
data = [
    {x : 100, y : 150},
    {x : 200, y : 250}
];
// these are some elements I'm using for debugging
click_count = d3.select('#click-count');
did_drag = d3.select('#did-drag');

function draw() {
    var drag_behavior,dragged = false;

    // clear all circles from the svg element
    d3.select('#test').selectAll('circle')
        .remove();

    drag_behavior = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(Object)
        .on("drag", function(d) {
            // indicate that dragging has occurred
            dragged = true;
            // update the data
            d.x = d3.event.x;
            // update the display
            d3.select(this).attr('cx',d.x);
        }).on('dragend',function() {
            // data has been updated. redraw.
            if(dragged) { draw(); }
        });

    d3.select('#test').selectAll('circle')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx',function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr('cy',function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr('r',20)
        .on('click',function() {
            did_drag.text(dragged.toString());
            if(!dragged) {
                // increment the click counter
                click_count.text(parseInt(click_count.text()) + 1);
            }
        }).call(drag_behavior);
}

draw();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After observing that the click required before my svg circles would start responding to click events again could happen *anywhere* in the document, I settled on a hack whereby I simulate a click event on the document (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706236/1015178) after the drag ends.  It's ugly, but it works.

Here's the function to simulate an event (again, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706236/1015178)

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
```

And here's the updated drag behavior:

```
drag_behavior = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(Object)
    .on("drag", function(d) {
        // indicate that dragging has occurred
        dragged = true;
        // update the data
        d.x = d3.event.x;
        // update the display
        d3.select(this).attr('cx',d.x);
    }).on('dragend',function() {
        // data has been updated. redraw.
        if(dragged) { draw(); }
        // simulate a click anywhere, so the svg circles
        // will start responding to click events again
        eventFire(document,'click');
    });
```

Here's the full working example of my hackish "fix":

http://jsfiddle.net/RRCyq/3/

Answer (score 6):

A little late to the party, buuuut...

The documentations suggests that you use `d3.event.defaultPrevented` in your `click` event to know whether or not the element was just dragged.  If you combine that with your `drag` and `dragend` events, a much cleaner approach is to call the exact function you want when necessary (see when and how `flashRect` is called):

http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/fE5gN/

```
var container,
    rect,
    dragBehavior,
    wasDragged = false;

container = d3.select('svg')
    .append('g');

rect = container.append('rect')
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 100);

dragBehavior = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', onDragStart)
    .on('drag', onDrag)
    .on('dragend', onDragEnd);

container
    .call(dragBehavior)
    .on('click', onClick);

function flashRect() {
    rect.attr('fill', 'red').transition().attr('fill', 'black');
}

function onDragStart() {
    console.log('onDragStart');
}

function onDrag() {
    console.log('onDrag');

    var x = (d3.event.sourceEvent.pageX - 50);

    container.attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ')');

    wasDragged = true;
}

function onDragEnd() {
    if (wasDragged === true) {
        console.log('onDragEnd');

        // always do this on drag end
        flashRect();
    }

    wasDragged = false;
}

function onClick(d) {
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented === false) {
        console.log('onClick');

        // only do this on click if we didn't just finish dragging
        flashRect();
    }
}
```

I didn't like the global variable, so I made a revision to use data: http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/fE5gN/1/

Comment: In 2015, still very helpful!