# Call functions in onclick directly

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am new to javascript and casperjs.I am trying to trigger a button for automating a specific task.  I can do it by `clicklabel()`.  I would like to know if there is direct way to call those functions.  There is a `sendAJAX` function in casperjs documentation.  Does it work in this case?

```
<a class="selection" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="function1(); function2();">New</a>
```

Comment: Did you try? yes it will work.

Comment: @gdoron Thanks for he quick reply.Did you mean the sendAJAX function?

Comment: Show us what you want to do, your question is vague and looks like a puzzle.

Comment: @gdoron i want to trigger the 'onclick' for the element shown.I can do it by casper.clicklabel('New').I want to know if i can call those functions independently somehow

Comment: I am trying to automate some tasks on a website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need the href in this case - just leave it blank.

For an answer to your question, however, there look to be two options.  The first, and best overall, is the jQuery .click() function.  jQuery is awesome, and if you're doing stuff with javascript, you owe it to yourself to learn (though it does take a little while to learn how to use it properly).  If you're not willing to take that time at the moment, however, I suggest [How to simulate a click with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/simulate-click-javascript) as looking like a workable javascript-only answer.

Comment: when i do document.getElementsByClassName('selection')[0].click() ,It shows error :undefined

Comment: I apologize.  I trusted the accuracy of w3schools.  I should not have done that.  Please find the corrected and somewhat more thorough answer above (including link).

Comment: you were right.i just missed one parameter for my function.Thanks a lot