# Javascript click() return undefined

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, click

I try to simulate click on a link with javascript

here is the code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('link-a')[2].click();
```

When i try this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('link-a')[2];
```

I have the link that ai want to simulate a click but when i add the click() function it's return undefined and there is no click at all...

can you help me please?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your browser support getElementByClassName ? : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: With pure javascript i don´t think this works, you have to something mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/simulate-click-javascript). Or just use jQuery.

Comment: I use the chrome console

Comment: [Your example works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Ta6nH/)

Comment: Please show an example with some HTML. The `click()` method is supposed to return undefined so that's not out of the ordinary. Also, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click

Answer (score 1):

so

```
document.getElementsByClassName('link-a')[2];
```

gives you back an HTML element.

and you can call "click()" on it, because click is a method it provides.

click does return undefined (as expected)