# Imitate changing select option by user

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, userscripts

I'm trying to deal with one userscript user may have installed when he visits my site. As it works in a sandbox, I can't directly turn off some of the userscript's features that interfere with my site's native functionality. So the only option for me is to access them though the UI. First I needed to change one particular checkbox. First I tried to use jQuery's `.val()` method but it did not work. Then I did this:

```
if($('#someinput:checked').length) $('#someinput')[0].click();
```

And then it worked, the unwanted feature got turned off. Next one was `<select>`. Just `.val()` did'n help as expected, so I also triggered the `change` event right after I changed the value:

```
$('select[name=someselect]').val(0);
$('select[name=someselect]')[0].change();
```

But it still does not work. I guess I need to trigger `change` event somehow more properly. How do I do that?

Comment: `$('#someinput)[0].click();` is missing a closing quote, are you sure it worked ?

Comment: @Gaurang Tandon Yes, I just mistyped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21292403/1561204):

Basically as far as I understand it fires all the native events properly and it's neatly wrapped into a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$('select[name="someselect"]').change();
```

instead of:

```
$('select[name=someselect]')[0].change();
```

because `$('select[name=someselect]')[0]` return a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: I don't get what you means. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Sorry, I just tested that again and found out that with checkbox both `$('#someinput')[0].click();` and `$('#someinput').click();` worked. Still `$('select[name="someselect"]').change();` doesn't.