# Why doesn't the 'change' event in jQuery fire onChange in ReactJS?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am writing tests for ReactJS components in karma + PhatomJS. I am rendering the component and **using jQuery** as a shortcut to target dom elements and simulate user actions. Clicking, text input, etc works fine. However, the selection in a select doesn't seem to execute the component's onChange event. Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import $ from 'jquery'

class SelectComponent extends React.Component {
    handleChange (event) {
        // This is NEVER fired
        doSomething()
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <select id='Fruits' onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
                <option value='A'>Apple</option>
                <option value='B'>Banana</option>
                <option value='C'>Cranberry</option>
            </select>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SelectComponent />, document.createElement('div'))

// Pragmatically change the selection
$('#Fruits').val('B').change()
```

However, without jQuery, it seems to work just fine. When I change the last line to:

```
const element = document.getElementById('Fruits')
element.value = value
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }))
```

**the callback in ReactJS gets fired**!

I cannot spot any difference. I thought that the code above is practically the same what jQuery does with .val('B').change(). Perhaps a jQuery ninja can give me a hint on this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work with jQuery `change()` because that doesn't trigger a "real" `change` event. It's a shortcut for [.trigger('change')](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) which says

> A call to .trigger() executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user

and

> Although .trigger() simulates an event activation, complete with a synthesized event object, it does not perfectly replicate a naturally-occurring event.

I believe this was done in order to help support very old versions of IE that had different handling of events.

That's the *why* of it at any rate, since that's what you wanted to know. Just firing the event natively makes your tests less coupled with your implementation choices.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger the "real" 'change' event with jQuery? I know, it's another question. But wondering if you know a solution. ^^

Comment: @RomanSemko I've been avoiding jQuery since we dropped IE8 support two years ago so I'm afraid I wouldn't know :)

Comment: @RomanSemko A quick google search came up with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21292403/957731) but it basically just wraps creating a native event into a plugin. Which might be exactly what you need to do unless something's been changed in v3.0

Comment: BTW, that question might serve as a duplicate of yours. I think the answer I linked is better than mine.