# Vue.js: update v-model value after triggering select change with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js, jquery-events

HTML:

```
<select v-model="model">
    <option hidden disabled v-bind:value="false" selected>Placeholder</option>
    <option v-for="item in array" v-bind:value="item.id"> @{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

I have a select much like the above and I'm using some jQuery to update the select box. I can't however seem to update the v-model to align with the jQuery change.

jQuery:

```
.on('mousedown', '.class', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('option:first').prop('selected', true).val(false).change();
});
```

The jQuery here listens for a `mousedown` event on a clear button which selects the placeholder option i.e. resetting the select box. However I was hoping `.val(false).change()` would be enough to trigger the v-model to update - it was not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing plenty more research since posting this I stumbled upon this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290775/jquery-el-triggerchange-doesnt-fire-native-listeners).

It's a problem with jQuery change event not firing native listeners.

To solve this problem I added a snippet based on the top voted answer found through that link.

```
evt.preventDefault();
$(this).removeClass('x onX').find('option:first').prop('selected', true);

let el = $(this).get(0);
let event = document.createEvent('Events');
event.initEvent('change', true, false);
el.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [v-model.lazy](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy) for this:

```
<select v-model.lazy="model">
```

Comment: Vue automatically knows to look for change events when v-model is added to a select box. So `.lazy` is only really necessary when used with say an `input`. I have tried this however and as expected it just gives the same result.